# Iterate two Java-8-Streams together

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to iterate two Java-8-Streams together, so that I have in each iteration-step two arguments.
Something like that, where `somefunction` produces something like `Stream<Pair<A,B>>`.

```
Stream<A> as;
Stream<B> bs;
somefunction (as, bs)
  .forEach ((a, b) -> foo (a, b));
// or something like
somefunction (as, bs)
  .forEach ((Pair<A, B> abs) -> foo (abs.left (), abs.right ()));
```

I want to know, if Java provides something like that, although there is no `Pair` in Java :-(
If there is no API-Function like that, is there another way of iterating two streams simultaniously?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
static <A, B> Stream<Pair<A, B>> zip(Stream<A> as, Stream<B> bs)
{
    Iterator<A> i=as.iterator();
    return bs.filter(x->i.hasNext()).map(b->new Pair<>(i.next(), b));
}
```

This does not offer parallel execution but neither did the original `zip` implementation.

And as [F. Böller has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059837/iterate-two-java-8-streams-together/24063511?noredirect=1#comment39119022_24063511) it doesn’t work if `bs` is infinite and `as` is not. For a solution which works for all possible combinations of infinite and finite streams, an intermediate `Iterator` which checks both sources within the `hasNext` method seems unavoidable¹:

```
static <A, B> Stream<Pair<A,B>> zip(Stream<A> as, Stream<B> bs) {
    Iterator<A> i1 = as.iterator();
    Iterator<B> i2 = bs.iterator();
    Iterable<Pair<A,B>> i=()->new Iterator<Pair<A,B>>() {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext();
        }
        public Pair<A,B> next() {
            return new Pair<A,B>(i1.next(), i2.next());
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(i.spliterator(), false);
}
```

If you want parallel capable zipping you should consider the *source* of the `Stream`. E.g. you can zip two `ArrayList`s (or any `RandomAccessList`) like

```
ArrayList<Foo> l1=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Bar> l2=new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, Math.min(l1.size(), l2.size()))
         .mapToObj(i->new Pair(l1.get(i), l2.get(i)))
         . …
```

---

¹(unless you implement a `Spliterator` directly)

Comment: Just found out, that this solution is not working for an infinite Stream of Bs. In this case it's an endless loop. The B-Stream has to be limited in some way. However, I didn't find a solution with small changes to your above code. The linked answer seems to work with infinite streams too: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23529010/3699131)

Comment: @F. Böller: right, there is no small change solving this. The solution you have linked might work but I recommend to be careful about licensing issues as the code has been c&p'ed from a beta jdk source as the answerer says by itself. You should also keep in mind that there might be other issues as the authors of the code might have had a reason to remove it from the jdk…