# Combine two streams with collation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to do some Matrix work in an efficient and flexible way and hoped I could practice my Java 8 using streams and lambdas and perhaps even get free parallelism out of it. One point I am struggling with is how to perform an operation on two streams putting the result into a third.

Consider the simple mechanism:

```
static final List<String> a = Arrays.asList("A", "A", "A");
static final List<String> b = Arrays.asList("B", "B", "B");

public void withoutStreams() {
    // The boring old way.
    List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator<String> ai = a.iterator(), bi = b.iterator(); ai.hasNext() && bi.hasNext();) {
        c.add(ai.next() + bi.next());
    }
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Works fine but I want to use Streams.

```
private void withStreams() {
    List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    combine(a.stream(), b.stream(), c, (String x, String y) -> x + y);
}

private void combine(Stream<String> a, Stream<String> b, List<String> c, BinaryOperator<String> op) {
    // What can I do here to make it happen?
}
```

I fully expect we will be filling `c` using a `Consumer` of some form but extra kudos for coming up with some way of referring to a specific cell of the matrix other than using (row,col) bearing in mind that the cells will be immutable.

Comment: This could be probably be achieved with a zip function, which unfortunately was removed the JDK 8 libraries at the end. But in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17640754/697630) you can find some interesting alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IntStream` class to simulate indexing and then `.mapToObj` to concatenate the corresponding to the index objects from `a` and `b`:

```
List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, Math.max(a.size(), b.size()))
                             .mapToObj(i -> a.get(i) + b.get(i))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Applied to your method, this will look like:

```
private void combine(List<String> a, List<String> b, List<String> c, BinaryOperator<String> op) {
    c = IntStream.range(0, Math.max(a.size(), b.size()))
                 .mapToObj(i -> op.apply(a.get(i), b.get(i)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However, if you don't want to change the method's signature, [here is a solution which works for all possible combinations of infinite and finite streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24063511/1003142):

```
private void combine(Stream<String> a, Stream<String> b, List<String> c, BinaryOperator<String> op) {
    Iterator<String> i1 = a.iterator();
    Iterator<String> i2 = b.iterator();
    Iterable<String> i = () -> new Iterator<String>() {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext();
        }
        public String next() {
            return op.apply(i1.next(), i2.next());
        }
    };
    c = StreamSupport.stream(i.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I can see that this would work but it kind of defeats the purpose - I was hoping to stream the data itself rather than indexes into the data. Secondly - if I apply this technique to matrices I would need a `Pair<int,int>` for row/col, not as elegant.

Comment: Not to mention that unless those lists are random access, accessing an indexed value directly might pay a performance price.

Comment: After your edit - the signature of my `combine` uses `Stream<String>` not `List<String>` - any chance of that working?

Comment: Nice - any ideas on how to hold a reference to the target cell (I will be consuming to a matrix of immutables). Could this be a lambda/closure or something?

Comment: Can you give some more details about what you're trying to achieve? :)

Comment: @kocko Beautiful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming style, using recursive (no loop):

```
static Stream<String> combine(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    if(a.isEmpty() ||  b.isEmpty()) {
        return Stream.empty();
    }

    return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(a.get(0) + b.get(0)),
            combine(a.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList()), 
                    b.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            );
}
```

plus: I vote up kocko's answer, my answer is for fun.

Comment: The solution could work if the JVM does last call optimization.