# Multiply & Sum two ArrayLists in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two ArrayLists, named A and B, of equal size containing some numbers. Now I want to calculate something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<A.size() && i<B.size(); i++) {
  sum += A.get(i)*B.get(i);
}
```

How can I achieve what I am doing above, calculating the sum, by using Java 8 features (streams, lambda expressions, etc) without using any extra user-defined methods?

Comment: You might get a better answer if you explain why the loop is not acceptable to you, but you can use the rather literal stream translation of that loop with `IntStream.range(0, A.size()).map(i -> A.get(i) * B.get(i)).sum()`.

Comment: Just for good programming measure: I don't see any proof that A and B are the same size.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I have no problems with using loops. I asked it because I am learning Java 8 features, should have included that in the post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate two Java-8-Streams together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059837/iterate-two-java-8-streams-together)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int sum = 
    IntStream.range(0, min(a.size(), b.size())
             .map(i -> a.get(i) * b.get(i))
             .sum();
```

Comment: although of course given the claim that they're already same-sized, no need for that `min()` call

Comment: I think it's multiplication, not addition. `a.get(i) + b.get(i)` should be `a.get(i) * b.get(i)`?

Comment: That's a neat solution.  I hadn't considered emitting the range of indices as a Stream.

Comment: How can this be adapted for `ArrayList` of `Double`s? I don't see a `range` method on `DoubleStream`

Comment: @Mubin - It will work "as is" for any collections that support positional access.

Comment: @Mubin the IntStream.range generates a Stream of indices, not a Stream of values to be multiplied.  All Lists are indexable by integer indexes regardless of contained types.

Comment: For using `ArrayLists` with `Double` values, I had to use `mapToDouble` instead of `map`, otherwise it was giving `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int`

Comment: @Mubin **IntStream.map** expects an **IntUnaryOperator** and returns an **IntStream**.  So **mapToDouble** is required so that you can provide a **IntToDoubleFunction** lamdba to get a **DoubleStream** for **sum()**. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-

Comment: this is a nice hack, but it's not really streaming the lists, you are simply creating an IntStream of Indexes. The main issue would again be performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = IntStream
            .range(0, min(a.size(), b.size())
            .map(i -> 
              (a.get(i).getValue() == null || b.get(i).getValue() == null) ? 0 :
                       (a.get(i).getValue() * b.get(i).getValue()))
            .sum();
```

Neat Solution!
I had a similar requirement, and I added ternary operator null check.
(In my scenario, my lists where of generic type and calculation was done on values within the object which could be null)