# Combine two lists of same size (and different type) into list of domain objects using java streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm having two lists of same size `ids` and `results` and I want to create new list with domain objects.

```
List<Id> ids = ...

List<Result> results = redisTemplate.opsForValue().multiGet.get(ids);

List<DomainObject> list = // list of domain objects new DomainObject(id, result);
```

Solution that I've used:

```
List<DomainObject> list = new ArrayList<>(ids.size());
for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
    list.add(new DomainObject(ids.get(i), results.get(i)));
}
```

Is there any more elegant way to do it eg. using streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to do it using guava `zip` operator.

```
List<DomainObject> list = Streams.zip(ids.stream(), results.stream(), DomainObject::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of this way with `Streams` would be :

```
List<DomainObject> list = IntStream.range(0, ids.size())
                            .mapToObj(i -> new DomainObject(ids.get(i), results.get(i))) 
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Or take a look at [*Iterate two Java-8-Streams*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059837/iterate-two-java-8-streams-together)

Comment: as there are no guarantees on the type returned then you should use `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` instead. otherwise if the implementation of `toList()` were to change in the future you might not get the same _thing_ that you'd expect.

Comment: Also to be more specific the collect terminal operation should be something along the lines of `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(ids.size())));`

Comment: @Aominè why it is useful to use the constructor with the size in parameter here ?