# iterating over two java streams with the same size and override values from one on another

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two Lists and they have same size. I would like to iterate over both of them simultaneously and override values from one stream on another stream.

For example I have two lists ListA and ListB with some data and they can be compared by id and I would like to get as a result like below:

```
List<SomeObject> listA;
List<AnotherObject> listB;

listA: {
[id=111;
name='AAA';
age=65],
[id=222;
name='BBB';
age=11],
}

listB: {
[id=111;
name='';
age=null],
[id=222;
name='';
age=null],
}

result:{
[id=111;
name='AAA';
age=65],
[id=222;
name='BBB';
age=11],
}
```

They have some other properties of course which are different and should stay as it is. So I need to override just two of them

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what doesn't work, so we can see what you have tried and why it differs from the expected result.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Stream`s for that? A simple for-loop is good enough.

Comment: You can map `SomeObject` to `AnotherObject` in the stream of `ListA`. `ListB` is not necessary.

Comment: See [Iterate two Java-8-Streams together - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059837/iterate-two-java-8-streams-together/24063511#24063511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a map from one list (grouping by `id`) for example from 'listB'
2. Iterate by other list (`listA`) with stream or for-loop, and for every item find by `id` corresponding item from created map.
3. If entries match by `id` replace all values that are `null` or empty string.