# Can I process 2 collections pair-wise with streams?

Tags: java, vector, collections, java-8

Suppose I wish to process 2 List of the same length.

A good example would be vector dot product.

Suppose vector a = [1 2 3], b = [0; 1; 2;], then a .* b = 1*0 + 2*1 + 3*2 = 8

Can I do this with stream?

Comment: This operation is called a [convolution/"zip"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip - and then in the example, is followed by a sum/fold.

Comment: yes, this is a duplicate of 17640754. 
for some reason my answer was deleted but you can get the code here:
 http://pastebin.com/R5Sx07HC

Comment: Yes, likely duplicate. The short answer is to use `IntStream.range` to drive the stream and to use those values to index into the arrays or lists.