# Java 8 streams adding values from two or more lists

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to get into Java 8 and get my head around streams and lambdas to solve various problems and got stuck on this specific one which I normally use a forEach and store the values in a Map to solve.

How would you write the code to get the expected list using the new features in Java 8  ?

```
List<Integer> voterA = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> voterB = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<List<Integer>> votes = Arrays.asList(voterA, voterB);

// expected list = (2,4,6,8,10)
List<Integer> sumVotes = ...
```

Comment: How would you solve it with enhanced-for-loop(s)?

Comment: Take a look to [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Answer (score 7):

That one isn't really doable the way you're hoping.  The closest you could get would probably be

```
IntStream.range(0, voterA.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> voterA.get(i) + voterB.get(i))
    .collect(toList());
```

...but there's no "zip" operation on streams, largely because two different streams can have backing spliterators that split at different points, so you can't line them up properly.

Comment: It's annoying that I can see exactly how I'd do this in C# in LINQ - in a pretty general way - but I'm still groping around when it comes to Java streams. Maybe when I get more practice...

Comment: I mean...I look at the Spliterator interface, and I don't think there's any _nice_ way to do zipping, just because `trySplit` allows the split to happen at an arbitrary point.  You can do indexing efficiently with SUBSIZED spliterators, and fall back to a less-efficient sequential approach for other spliterators, but I don't think there's anything you can do with zipping.

Comment: Here's the C# version, complete with 3 voters with different lengths of lists: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/2c1db126e424cf58cb69

Comment: I mean, that translates pretty directly to https://gist.github.com/lowasser/e1b57e1a9358cbf52cc6

Comment: Right. It's really just the primitives aspect (and the explicit stream call) that makes it uglier than the C# - your version doesn't have the conditional handling of lists of unequal sizes, but even I can work out how I'd do that ;)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Getting the spliterators to line up their splits, especially in parallel, is certainly a big issue. Another issue is that you really want the result of zipping two (or N) streams to be another stream. What would its element type be? A `Pair` or `Tuple` class? Or provide a `BiFunction` that combines elements pairwise? But we don't have N-ary functions. We're still wrestling with this, but it doesn't look like anything will emerge until we have value types (> Java 9).

Comment: I'd definitely stick to a `BiFunction`, which can be `Pair::of` if necessary; strong -1 to tuple types.  I'd be inclined to accept the limitation to the n=2 case, which can be expanded with currying if necessary -- that is, returning a stream of functions, to be zipped with a stream of arguments.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Seems reasonable to **me**, but I accept that others would be dissatisfied with these limitations. Plus it would likely get in the way of improvements when and if value types come along. Meanwhile, streaming over an `IntRange` and using the values as indexes into multiple arrays/lists seems to satisfy a good chunk of use cases, though by no means all of them.

Answer (score 2):

JDK doesn't provide the 'zip' API. But it can be done with third library [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common):

```
List<Integer> voterA = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> voterB = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

List<Integer> sumVotes = Stream.zip(voterA, voterB, (a, b) -> a + b).toList();
```

Disclosure： I'm the developer of abacus-common.