# Why the tryAdvance of stream.spliterator() may accumulate items into a buffer?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Getting a `Spliterator` from a `Stream` pipeline may return an instance of a [StreamSpliterators.WrappingSpliterator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/StreamSpliterators.java#StreamSpliterators.WrappingSpliterator). For example, getting the following `Spliterator`:

```
Spliterator<String> source = new Random()
            .ints(11, 0, 7) // size, origin, bound
            .filter(nr -> nr % 2 != 0)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .spliterator();
```

Given the above `Spliterator<String> source`, when we traverse the elements individually through the `tryAdvance (Consumer<? super P_OUT> consumer)` method of `Spliterator`, which in this case is an instance of [StreamSpliterators.WrappingSpliterator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/StreamSpliterators.java#StreamSpliterators.WrappingSpliterator), it will first accumulate items into an internal buffer, before consuming those items, as we can see in [StreamSpliterators.java#298](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/StreamSpliterators.java#298). From a simple point of view, the `doAdvance()` inserts items first into `buffer` and then it gets the next item and pass it to `consumer.accept (…)`.

```
public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super P_OUT> consumer) {
    boolean hasNext = doAdvance();
    if (hasNext)
        consumer.accept(buffer.get(nextToConsume));
    return hasNext;
}
```

However, I am not figuring out the need of this `buffer`.

In this case, why the `consumer` parameter of the `tryAdvance` is not simply used as a terminal [`Sink`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Sink.java) of the pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mostly agree with great @Holger answer, but I would put accents differently. I think it is hard for you to understand the need for a buffer because you have very simplistic mental model of what Stream API allows. If one thinks about Stream as a sequence of `map` and `filter`, there is no need for additional buffer because those operations have 2 important "good" properties:

1. Work on one element at a time
2. Produce 0 or 1 element as a result

However those are not true in general case. As @Holger (and I in [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839103/182660)) mentioned there is already `flatMap` in Java 8 that breaks rule #2 and in Java 9 they've finally added [takeWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) that actually transforms on whole `Stream` -> `Stream` rather than on a per-element basis (and that is AFAIK the first intermediate shirt-circuiting operation).

Another point I don't quite agree with @Holger is that I think that the most fundamental reason is a bit different than the one he puts in the second paragraph (i.e. a) that you may call `tryAdvance` post the end of the `Stream` many times and b) that  "*there is no guaranty that the caller will always pass the same consumer*"). I think that the most important reason is that `Spliterator`  being functionally identical to `Stream` has to support short-circuiting and laziness (i.e. ability to not process the whole `Stream` or else it can't support unbound streams). In other words, even if Spliterator API (quite strangely) required that you must use the same `Consumer` object for all calls of all methods for a given `Spliterator`, you would still need `tryAdvance` and that `tryAdvance` implementation would still have to use some buffer. You just can't stop processing data if all you've got is `forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> )` so you can't implement anything similar to `findFirst` or `takeWhile` using it. Actually this is one of the reasons why inside JDK implementation uses `Sink` interface rather than `Consumer` (and what "wrap" in `wrapAndCopyInto` stands for): `Sink` has additional `boolean cancellationRequested()` method.

So ***to sum up***: a buffer is required because we want `Spliterator`:

1. To use simple `Consumer` that provides no means to report back end of processing/cancellation
2. To provide means to stop processing of the data by a request of the (logical) consumer.

Note that those two are actually slightly contradictory requirements.

**Example and some code**

Here I'd like to provide some example of code that I believe is impossible to implement without additional buffer given current API contract (interfaces). This example is based on your example.

There is simple [Collatz sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) of integers that is conjectured to always eventually hit 1. AFAIK this conjecture is not proved yet but is verified for many integers (at least for whole 32-bit int range).

So assume that the problem we are trying to solve is following: from a stream of Collatz sequences for random start numbers in range from 1 to 1,000,000 find the first that contains "123" in its decimal representation.

Here is a solution that uses just `Stream` (not a `Spliterator`):

```
static String findGoodNumber() {
    return new Random()
            .ints(1, 1_000_000) // unbound!
            .flatMap(nr -> collatzSequence(nr))
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .filter(s -> s.contains("123"))
            .findFirst().get();
}
```

where `collatzSequence` is a function that returns `Stream` containing the Collatz sequence until the first 1 (and for nitpickers let it also stop when current value is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE /3` so we don't hit overflow).

Every such `Stream` returned by `collatzSequence` is bound. Also standard `Random` will eventually generate every number in the provided range. It means that we are guaranteed that there eventually will be some "good" number in the stream (for example just `123`) and `findFirst` is short-circuiting so the whole operation will actually terminate. However no reasonable Stream API implementation can predict this.

Now let's assume that for some strange reason you want to perform the same thing using intermediate `Spliterator`. Even though you have only one piece of logic and no need for different `Consumer`s, you can't use `forEachRemaining`. So you'll have to do something like this:

```
static Spliterator<String> createCollatzRandomSpliterator() {
    return new Random()
            .ints(1, 1_000_000) // unbound!
            .flatMap(nr -> collatzSequence(nr))
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .spliterator();
}

static String findGoodNumberWithSpliterator() {
    Spliterator<String> source = createCollatzRandomSpliterator();

    String[] res = new String[1]; // work around for "final" closure restriction

    while (source.tryAdvance(s -> {
        if (s.contains("123")) {
            res[0] = s;
        }
    })) {
        if (res[0] != null)
            return res[0];
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Impossible");
}
```

It is also important that for some starting numbers the Collatz sequence will contain several matching numbers. For example, both `41123` and `123370` (= 41123*3+1) contain "123". It means that we really don't want our `Consumer` to be called post the first matching hit. But since `Consumer` doesn't expose any means to report end of processing, `WrappingSpliterator` can't just pass our `Consumer` to the inner `Spliterator`. The only solution is to accumulate all results of inner `flatMap` (with all the post-processing) into some buffer and then iterate over that buffer one element at a time.

Comment: Note that `flatMap` doesn’t respect `cancellationRequested()` when traversing the substream, so it doesn’t matter whether the end is a `Consumer` or `Sink`. All that matters, is that the receiver is capable of ignoring excess elements, which is *one* reason to buffer in `WrappingSpliterator`. But it’s hard to believe that the main reason for this design is to serve *one* poorly implemented operation (`flatMap`, which still breaks if the substream is infinite, even when a match has been found and `cancellationRequested()` returns `true`)…

Comment: @Holger, yes in current implementation `flatMap` can't be stopped by `cancellationRequested` but this is IMHO implementation details. What I'm trying to say, that given `Consumer` as the basis of the API you can't avoid buffer even **_theoretically_**. Given something like `Sink` one theoretically can.

Comment: After some more thinking I'd like to retract the claim that you theoretically can't implement `tryAdvance` without a buffer if you have only `Consumer`. You can, but the design will be much more complicated: on every stage of the intermediate operations you will have to track current iteration state to be able to process exactly one "output" element.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that this is the `Spliterator` returned by the `public` method `Stream.spliterator()`, so no assumptions about the caller can be made (as long as it is within the contract).

The `tryAdvance` method may get called once for each of the stream’s elements and once more to detect the end of the stream, well, actually, it might get called an arbitrary number of times even after hitting the end. And there is no guaranty that the caller will always pass the same consumer.

To pass a consumer directly to the source spliterator without buffering, you will have to compose a consumer that will perform all pipeline stages, i.e. call a mapping function and use its result or test a predicate and not call the downstream consumer if negative and so on. The consumer passed to the source spliterator would also be responsible to notify the `WrappingSpliterator` somehow about a value being rejected by the filter as the source spliterator’s `tryAdvance` method still returns `true` in that case and the operation would have to be repeated then.

As [Eugene correctly mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47038528/2711488), this is the one-fits-all implementation that doesn’t consider how many or what kind of pipeline stages are there. The costs of composing such a consumer *could* be heavy and *might* have to be reapplied for each `tryAdvance` call, read for every stream element, e.g. when different consumers are passed to `tryAdvance` or when equality checks do not work. Keep in mind that consumers are often implemented as lambda expressions and the identity or equality of the instances produced by lambda expressions is unspecified.

So the `tryAdvance` implementation avoids these costs by composing only one consumer instance on the first invocation that will always store the element into the same buffer, also allocated on the first invocation, if not rejected by a filter. Note that under normal circumstances, the buffer will only hold one element. Afaik, [`flatMap` is the only operation that may push more elements to the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/2711488). But note that the existence of this non-lazy behavior of `flatMap` is also the reason why this buffering strategy is required, at least when `flatMap` is involved, to ensure that the `Spliterator` implementation handed out by a `public` method will fulfill the contract of passing at most one element to the consumer during one invocation of `tryAdvance`.

In contrast, when you call `forEachRemaining`, these problems do not exist. There is only one `Consumer` instance during the entire operation and the non-laziness of `flatMap` doesn’t matter either, as all elements will get consumed anyway. Therefore, a non-buffering transfer will be attempted, as long as no previous `tryAdvance` call was made that could have caused buffering of some elements:

```
     public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super P_OUT> consumer) {
         if (buffer == null && !finished) {
             Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
             init();

             ph.wrapAndCopyInto((Sink<P_OUT>) consumer::accept, spliterator);
             finished = true;
         }
         else {
             do { } while (tryAdvance(consumer));
         }
     }
```

As you can see, as long as the `buffer` has not been initialized, i.e. no previous `tryAdvance` call was made, `consumer::accept` *is* bound as `Sink` and a complete direct transfer made.

Comment: *obviously* for me - you were very much expected here

Comment: I just realize the problem when you said “a value being rejected by the filter … and the operation would have to be repeated then.” So, at (`if (predicate.test(u)) downstream.accept(u);`) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#174, I see there is no `else` and no way to notify the source that it should advance another item. Again, I see the problem when the `flatMap` consumes the sub-stream in bulk `result.sequential().forEach(downstream);` instead of buffering and invoking `downstream.accept(u);` one by one.

Comment: @Miguel Gamboa: the notification was necessary if `tryAdvance` did consumer composition without buffering. But with the actual implementation, a simple `if(predicate.test(u)) downstream.accept(u);` works, as it only comes into play if a) the downstream consumer will consume all elements anyway or b) the buffering strategy is used where the caller can check afterwards whether the buffer contains a new element, like in `WrappingSpliterator`. Note that all short-circuiting operations are capable of handling this too, i.e. do recheck whether an element has been received and ignore excess elements.

Comment: @Holger It is not easy (at least for me) to realize how all these pieces interact each other and play together to process the `Stream` pipeline. There is too much complexity and the API and the source code are not enough to clarify the `Stream` internals. Even the [Streams under the hood](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java-streams-3-brian-goetz/index.html), from Brian Goetz, give no details behind the `Spliterator`. Is there any further reading that can help me understand the details about `Sink`, `ReferencePipeline`, `PipelineHelper`, `TerminalOp`, etc?

Comment: No, I don't know about any additional literature about the internals and considering the size of the potential audience, I do not expect any to show up in the future. I also think the chosen code structure is not very straight-forward, however, I understand it, because I've implemented a similar software and do remember which challenges I was faced with and can retrace the design decisions.

Answer (score 5):

This is something that I've read from Holger quite in a few posts and I'll just sum it up here; if there's a certain exact duplicate (I'll try to find one) - I will close and delete my answer in respect to that one.

First, is why `WrappingSpliterator` are needed in the first place - for stateful operations like `sorted`, `distinct`, etc - but I think you already understood that. I assume for `flatMap` also - since it is eager.

Now, when you call `spliterator`, IFF there are no stateful operations there is no real reason to wrap that into a `WrappingSpliterator` obviously, but **at the moment** this is not done. This could be changed in a future release - where they can detect if there are `stateful operations` before you call `spliterator`; but they don't do that now and simply treat *every operation as stateful*, thus wrapping it into `WrappingSpliterator`

Answer (score 3):

`Spliterators` are designed to handle sequential processing of each item in encounter order, and parallel processing of items in some order. Each method of the `Spliterator` must be able to support both early binding and late binding. The buffering is intended to gather data into suitable, processable chunks, that follow the requirements for ordering, parallelization and mutability.

In other words, `tryAdvance()` is not the only method in the class, and other methods have to work with each other to deliver the external contract. To do that, in the face of sub-classes that may override some or all of the methods, requires that each method obey its internal contract.