# Stream spliterator implementation detail

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

While looking into the source code of the `WrappingSpliterator::trySplit`, I was very mislead by it's implementation:

```
    @Override
    public Spliterator<P_OUT> trySplit() {
        if (isParallel && buffer == null && !finished) {
            init();

            Spliterator<P_IN> split = spliterator.trySplit();
            return (split == null) ? null : wrap(split);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

And if you are wondering why this matters, is because for example this:

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)
      .stream()
      .filter(x -> x != 1)
      .spliterator();
```

is using it. In my understanding the addition of any intermediate operation to a stream, will cause that code to be triggered.

Basically this method says that unless the stream is parallel, treat this Spliterator as one that can not be split, at all. And this matters to me. In one of my methods (this is how I got to that code), I get a `Stream` as input and "parse" it in smaller pieces, manually, with `trySplit`. You can think for example that I am trying to do a `findLast` from a `Stream`.

And this is where my desire to split in smaller chunks is nuked, because as soon as I do:

```
Spliterator<T> sp = stream.spliterator();
Spliterator<T> prefixSplit = sp.trySplit();
```

I find out that `prefixSplit` is `null`, meaning that I basically can't do anything else other than consume the entire `sp` with `forEachRemaning`.

And this is a bit weird, *may be* it makes some sense for when `filter` is present; because in this case the only way (in my understanding) a `Spliterator` could be returned is using some kind of a `buffer`, may be even with a predefined size (much like `Files::lines`). But why this:

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)
      .stream()
      .sorted()
      .spliterator()
      .trySplit();
```

returns `null` is something I don't understand. `sorted` is a stateful operation that buffers the elements anyway, without actually reducing or increasing their initial number, so at least theoretically this can return something other than `null`...

Comment: Well... maybe because the stream is not parallel? Obvious question... Have you tried `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4).parallelStream()......`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner of course... :) But if you remove `filter` and the stream is not parallel either, the splitting will work. The documentation does not say that this must happen for a parallel stream.

Comment: from javadoc:      * <p>This method may return {@code null} for any reason,
     * including emptiness, inability to split after traversal has
     * commenced, data structure constraints, and efficiency
     * considerations.

Comment: @Wisthler yup I read that, it's just it feels kind of weird, I guess

Comment: When you don’t chain an intermediate operation, `spliterator()` will just return the source spliterator, i.e. `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5) .stream() .spliterator() .getClass() == Arrays.spliterator(new Integer[] { 1,2,3,4,5 }) .getClass()`. Such a spliterator does not even know whether the Stream is parallel or if a Stream exist at all. And no, `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5) .parallelStream() .filter(x -> x != 1) .spliterator();` does *not* need any buffering.

Comment: @Holger right, I have seen that the source spliterator is returned in case there are no intermediate operations, even the `WrappingSpliterator` "knows" about it via `spliteratorSupplier`. The second point is that I *thought* it might be implemented with a buffer, I looked up the implementation now and you are right, it splits the source spliterator...  so the question in this case would be is this is a deliberate decision for a sequential stream? do you happen to know the reasons for this? thank you

Comment: Of course, it’s a deliberate decision, as someone put the `isParallel` into the `if (isParallel && …` line. Whether there is a reason (and I suppose you mean “good reason”) for that, is a different question. I don’t see any advantage in this restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `spliterator()` on a `Stream`, there are only two possible outcomes with the current implementation.

If the stream has no intermediate operations you’ll get the source spliterator that has been used to construct the stream and whose splitting capability is entirely independent from the stream’s parallel state, as in fact, the spliterator doesn’t know anything about the stream.

Otherwise, you’ll get a `WrappingSpliterator`, which will encapsulate a source `Spliterator` and a pipeline state, expressed as `PipelineHelper`. This combination of `Spliterator` and `PipelineHelper` does not need to work in parallel and, in fact, would not work in case of `distinct()`, as the `WrappingSpliterator` will get an entirely different combination, depending on whether the Stream is parallel or not.

For stateless intermediate operations, it would not make a difference though. But, as discussed in “[Why the tryAdvance of stream.spliterator() may accumulate items into a buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47036993/2711488)”, the `WrappingSpliterator` is a “one-fits-all implementation” that doesn’t consider the actual nature of the pipeline, so its limitations are the superset of all possible limitations of all supported pipeline stages. So the existence of one scenario that wouldn’t work when ignoring the `parallel` flag is enough to forbid splitting for all pipelines when not being `parallel`.