# Read text file and convert to 2d int array depending on input in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, java-8

I read a text file that looks like this:

```
operationName1 Value
```

There is a variable number of lines, with different operations and corresponding value. I can read the file and get a 2D String array as the output. This is my code.

```
try{
    Path path = Paths.get("./myFile.txt");
    String[][] array = Files.lines(path)
                .map(s -> s.split("\\s+", 2))
                .map(a -> new String[]{a[0], a[1]})
                .toArray(String[][]::new);
    }catch(IOException e){  
}
```

Question: How could I change my code to get a 2d int array instead, where operationName1 would be "0" and operationName2 would be "1" (there is only two possible operation, each defined by a specific string)?

This text file:

```
operationOne 5
OtherOp 999
operationOne 8
operationOne 2
```

Would become that 2d int array:

```
[[0,5],[1,999],[0,8],[0,2]]
```

The index is important too. So the 1st line of the text file is the 1st line of my array.

PS: If there is a better syntax (a more recent one), I am open to suggestion.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey David, why not use the answer from the previous question and customize it?

Comment: You have the value in `a[0]`. Test what this value is and map it to the corresponding number either 0 or 1.

Comment: Why are you trying to use streams here? Do you plan using parallelism? If not then probably simple loop would be much more readable (and probably little faster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need [parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html)? ... this could be one approach

```java
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
Map<String, Integer> known = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Path path = Paths.get("./myFile.txt");
int[][] array = Files.lines(path)
    .map(s -> s.split("\\s+", 2))
    .map(a -> new int[]{
        known.computeIfAbsent(a[0],
                k -> atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()),
        Integer.parseInt(a[1])
    })
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: or see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878981/java-8-equivalent-to-getlinenumber-for-streams

Comment: Note that there is no reason to use `Integer[][]` instead of `int[][]` here…

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the Scanner class for read text files

```
ArrayList<String[]> array = new ArrayList();
Scanner scan= new Scanner(new File("./myFile.txt"));
String str;
String auxiliary= new String[2];
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    str= scan.readLine();
    auxiliary=str.split(" "); // you can use also the \\s
    for(int i=0; i<array.size();i++){
        if(array.get(i)[0].equals(auxiliary[0])){
           String  aux2[]={i,auxiliary[1]};
           break;
        }
   }
   String  aux2[]={array.size,auxiliary[1]};
}
```

I hope it helped.

# EDIT: Corrected some issues

Comment: Few problems: (1) Scanner doesn't return `null` when there are no more lines. It throws exception. So instead of `while(str!=NULL)` ((2) you probably meant `null` - Java is case-sensitive) you should use something like `while(scan.hasNextLine())`. (3) `split` expects string `" "` not char `' '` as argument. (Improvement) In most cases there is no need to use `split` when we have Scanner. We usually use `haveNext` or `haveNext*Type*` here if we know how many elements will appear in each line (we just need to use then `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine`).

Comment: Thanks. I have in the last 3 month worked hard in C, I have swapped some things. But I have fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit long, but it allows you to go operationName1...operationNameN

I always try to keep the code clean, so if you have any questions just ask

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            File file = new File("test.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            ArrayList<String> operations = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

            String line;
            String[] array;

            int index;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                array = line.split(" ");

                if((index = hasOperation(array[0], operations)) == -1)
                {
                    operations.add(array[0]);
                    index = operations.size()-1;
                    points.add(new Point(index, Integer.parseInt(array[1])));
                }
                else
                {
                    points.add(new Point(index, Integer.parseInt(array[1])));
                }
            }

            System.out.print("[");
            for(int i = 0; i < points.size()-1; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(points.get(i).toString() + ",");
            }
            System.out.println(points.get(points.size()-1).toString()+"]");
    }



    public static int hasOperation(String operation, ArrayList<String> operations ){

        for(int index = 0; index < operations.size(); index++)
        {
            if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(operations.get(index)))
                return index;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}

public class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;


public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
    }
}
```