# How to print two lists together using Stream API java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists as follow

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("James","John","Fred");
List<Integer> ages = Arrays.asList(25,35,15);
```

What i want to do is to print those two lists like so

```
James:25
John:35
Fred:15
```

It is easy to do it using the classic way

```
for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++){
    System.out.println(names.get(i)+":"+ages.get(i));
}
```

*Is there a way to do it using Stream API java 8?*

What i am able to do is to print only one single list

```
names.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an `IntStream` to generate the indices, and then map each index to the `String` you want to create.

```
IntStream.range(0, Math.min(names.size(), ages.size()))
         .mapToObj(i -> names.get(i)+":"+ages.get(i))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Also you might be interested in this SO question [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip), because this is the kind of functionality you're asking for.

Answer (score 7):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library has some syntactic sugar for this case:

```
StreamEx.zip(names, ages, (name, age) -> name+":"+age).forEach(System.out::println)
```

Basically inside it's the same as in accepted answer. The only difference is that `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown if size of lists differs.

Answer (score 1):

While Alexis C. answer is correct, one would argue it is the easiest way to achieve requested behavior in Java 8. I propose:

```
int[] i = {0};
names.forEach(name -> {
    System.out.println(name + ages.get(i[0]++));
});
```

Or even without index:

```
List<Integer> agesCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>(ages);
names.forEach(name -> {
    System.out.println(name + agesCopy.remove(0));
});
```

Comment: I think this will print only the first element of `ages` because you make a new iterator each time.

Comment: Second solution could be very expensive because of list copy and items removing from the beginning.

Comment: neither solution takes consideration of the fact that `forEach` ignores encounter order