# How to calculate the rank of a player from a list

Tags: java, java-8

Say I have following simple data structure.

```
public class Player {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer scores;

    //getter setter
}
```

So far so good. Now question is , how do I get what's a players rank? 
I have another data structure for ranking, that is-

```
public class Ranking {
    private Integer score;
    private Integer rank;

    //getter/setter

}
```

So I have a list of player and i want to compute a list of ranking and I would like to use java8 stream api.

I have a service named `PlayerService` as following

```
public class PlayerService {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;


    public List<Ranking> findAllRanking(Long limit) {
        List<Player> players = playerRepository.findAll();

       // calculation 

        return null;
    }
```

The calculation is simple, whoever has most score has most ranking.

If I have `5,7,8,9,3` scores then ranking would be

```
rank score 
  1   9
  2   8 
  3   7
  4   5
  5   3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is unclear.  It's hard to tell what you are trying to do, what the link is between both classes, what list you are referring to in your title, etc.  Do you have more code of what you have tried to calculate the ranking?

Comment: please provide what you have tried

Comment: added a few more details

Comment: Where is a player with score 3 in the ranking?

Comment: @saka1029 I meant onward . however added that one aslo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
     List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>() {{
        add(new Player(1L, "a", 5));
        add(new Player(2L, "b", 7));
        add(new Player(3L, "c", 8));
        add(new Player(4L, "d", 9));
        add(new Player(5L, "e", 3));
        add(new Player(6L, "f", 8));
     }};
     int[] score = {Integer.MIN_VALUE};
     int[] no = {0};
     int[] rank = {0};
     List<Ranking> ranking = players.stream()
         .sorted((a, b) -> b.getScores() - a.getScores())
         .map(p -> {
             ++no[0];
             if (score[0] != p.getScores()) rank[0] = no[0];
             return new Ranking(rank[0], score[0] = p.getScores());
         })
         // .distinct() // if you want to remove duplicate rankings.
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
     System.out.println(ranking);
    // result:
    // rank=1, score=9
    // rank=2, score=8
    // rank=2, score=8
    // rank=4, score=7
    // rank=5, score=5
    // rank=6, score=3
```

The variables `score`, `no` and `rank` are free variables in the lambda function in `.map()`.  So they must not be reassigned.  If their types are `int` instead of `int[]`, you cannot compile the code.

Comment: what if the score is between two values in the array.  Like we have an array like this [5889,6050] and the player score is 5999.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the accepted answer is that once you turn the stream in parallel (`players.parallelStream()`), you'll get unexpected results, because of race conditions when you read/update the value from the singletons arrays.

Maybe you could decompose your task into multiple steps. First sort the list of scores into reverse order, and then generate a stream of indices. From there you map each index to its corresponding rank.

You need to test multiple conditions into the `mapToObj` statement if you need to have the same rank for a same score. It makes the code not very pretty but you can always extract this in a helper method.

```
List<Integer> scores = players.stream().map(Player::getScores).sorted(reverseOrder()).collect(toList());

List<Ranking> rankings =
        IntStream.range(0, scores.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> i == 0 ? new Ranking(1, scores.get(i)) :
                                        scores.get(i - 1).equals(scores.get(i)) ? new Ranking(i, scores.get(i)) :
                                                                                  new Ranking(i + 1, scores.get(i)))
                .collect(toList());
```

That said, if you don't plan to parallelize this step, I would go with the good old for-loop.

If you don't need to have the same rank for the same score, you can check this thread [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip), for example with [proton-pack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack):

```
List<Ranking> rankings = StreamUtils.zip(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, players.size()).boxed(),
                                         players.stream().map(Player::getScores).sorted(reverseOrder()),
                                         Ranking::new)
                                    .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get a better solution, if you rethink your prerequisites first. As a side note, I don’t understand, why you are using `Integer` throughout your code. If you really consider `null` a possible value for `rank` or `scores`, the solution will become much more complicated. Since I doubt that this is what you want, I recommend using `int` instead.

The biggest obstacle is your requirement of producing this rather superfluous `Ranking` instances. All you need, are the scores as once sorted, their rank is implied by their positions:

```
List<Integer> rankAndScore = players.stream().map(Player::getScores)
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(toList());
```

this resulting list contains the scores in descending order and the rank is implied by the position, the first item has the first rank, the second item the second, and so on. There is no need to explicitly store the rank numbers. The only thing to care is that the collection indices start with zero whereas the ranks start with one.

One way to print the values as in your question is:

```
System.out.println("rank\tscore");
IntStream.range(0, rankAndScore.size())
    .forEachOrdered(r->System.out.println(r+1+"\t"+rankAndScore.get(r)));
```

Alternatively, you could simply use an `int[]` array to represent rank and score:

```
int[] rankAndScore = players.stream().mapToInt(Player::getScores).sorted().toArray();
System.out.println("rank\tscore");
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, rankAndScore.length)
    .forEachOrdered(r->System.out.println(r+"\t"+rankAndScore[rankAndScore.length-r]));
```

The `IntStream` doesn’t support sorting in descending order but as shown, it can be simply fixed by sorting to ascending order and adapting the processing of the array.

Comment: what if the score is between two values in the array.  Like we have an array like this [5889,6050] and the player score is 5999.

Comment: @MR.Robot the array is generated from the actual scores. It is impossible to have a score not contained in the array and it is impossible to have an array entry not matching an actual player score. The whole point of this operation is to get you a sorted array of actual player scores.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the Player to have as an attribute, a Ranking, right? Why not add a member variable (or instance variable) in the player's class. I believe we call this "aggregation" or "Object composition" in object oriented programming.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Consider this...

```
 public class Player {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer scores;
    private Ranking rank;
    ...
    //You can add a constructor that include the Ranking, you can also add setter and getters to set the Ranking object for this player. 

    public int getRank()
    {
        return rank.getRank(); //assuming class Ranking has getRank() method
    }
    public void setRank(int rank)
    {
         rank.setRank(rank); //assuming class Ranking has setRank()
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is that you expected? You wanted getters and setters.

Comment: @UmaKanth Ya, thats what I wanted. Good that you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sort the payers according to their score?
so.. something along those lines:

```
public class PlayerService { 

@Autowired 
private PlayerRepository playerRepository;


public List<Ranking> findAllRanking(Long limit) {
    List<Player> players = playerRepository.findAll();

   // --- sorting players according to their scores
   Collections.sort(players, new Comparator<Player>(){
          @Override
          public int compare(Players thiz, Player that){
                 return new Integer(thiz.scores).compareTo(that.scores);
           });

   List<Ranking> rankingList = new ArrayList<>();
   int i = 0;
   for(Player p : players){
       rankingList.add(new Ranking(p.score, ++i));
   }

    return rankingList; 
}
```

I leave that as an exercise to you to determine if that produces your wanted order or the exact reverse.

Comment: well, I knew this solution, I was looking something better that can be done with stream api and  lambda expression . Thanks btw