# How to compose two collections item with item?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to aggregate two collections one item at a time? For example:

```
L1: {1,2,3,4}
L2: {1,2,3,4}
```

I want to aggregate the two, L1 and L2 so that I have a returning

```
L3: {2, 4, 6, 8}
```

Hence `L3[i] = L2[i] + L3[i]`

How can I accomplish this using lambdas?

Comment: This looks like the zip function. A search on google wielded [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip).

Comment: well, you are right.... :( missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @Mephy seems that zip, didn't make it in the jdk 8 official release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could play with `IntStream`:

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(l1.size(), l2.size()))
                                .map(i -> l1.get(i) + l2.get(i))
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @kocko - I've tried it, but it doesn't compile...I'm I missing something?

Comment: @kocko - it works, thank you. You'd be my hero if you adapt your example with an example to collect in a list.

Comment: You can almost always replace `.map(…).boxed()` with `.mapToObj(…)`

Answer (score 1):

These code snippets do the job:

Solution 1 (simplest approach):

```
public static Collection<Integer> sumCollectionElements(Collection<Integer> L1, Collection<Integer> L2) {
    final Iterator<Integer> iterator = L2.iterator();
    return L1.stream()
            .limit(Math.min(L1.size(), L2.size()))
            .map(integer -> integer + iterator.next())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Solution 2 (more general approach -> [gist](https://gist.github.com/kjkrol/51a5a7612f0411849c62)):

```
public static <A, B, C> Stream<C> zip(Stream<A> streamA, Stream<B> streamB, BiFunction<A, B, C> zipper) {
    final Iterator<A> iteratorA = streamA.iterator();
    final Iterator<B> iteratorB = streamB.iterator();
    final Iterator<C> mergedIterator = new Iterator<C>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iteratorA.hasNext() && iteratorB.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public C next() {
            return zipper.apply(iteratorA.next(), iteratorB.next());
        }
    };
    return iteratorToFiniteStream(mergedIterator);
}

public static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToFiniteStream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    final Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Comment: any idea how to get rid of the iterator? In order to resume everything in using streams?

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP there is a solution for you. Please review this GitHub project:
https://github.com/poetix/protonpack and check method StreamUtils#zip

Comment: yeah I know this one, I was thinking about something that exists in the code base of jdk 8. Thank you!

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP Maybe my gist will satisfy you?

Comment: With third-party code it could be even shorter: `List<Integer> l3 = StreamEx.zip(l1, l2, Integer::sum).toList();` (using my StreamEx library, I'm just trying to limit myself and not to advertise it too often, so I didn't post an answer). Sometimes having additional dependencies not an option.

Comment: @TagirValeev thank you! Leaving your modesty aside, could you please share the link the official repository of your library? Thank you :).

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP, ok if OP asks, I wrote an answer :-)

Comment: @TagirValeev I've seen your lib in GitHub its great!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using third-party libraries, consider my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which enhances standard Java Stream API. Your problem can be solved like this:

```
List<Integer> l3 = StreamEx.zip(l1, l2, Integer::sum).toList();
```

At a first glance the [`StreamEx.zip`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#zip-java.util.List-java.util.List-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method is similar to [protonpack zip](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack/blob/249c3574a33eba3467a79512f0dcca5b34ad89c1/src/main/java/com/codepoetics/protonpack/StreamUtils.java#L39) method. However it zips not the streams, but random access lists (like `ArrayList` or `Arrays.asList`) which allows proper parallelization. Internally it's close to the @kocko solution with minor differences:

- If input lists have different size, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.
- Internally the separate spliterator is used which might work somewhat faster in some scenarios.

Also note the usage of [`toList()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#toList--) method which is a shortcut for `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Answer (score -1):

```
L1 = {1,2,3,4}  
L2 = {1,2,3,4}

L3 = map(lambda L1,L2:L1+L2, L1,L2)

Output: [2, 4, 6, 8]
```