# How to append the elements of one Set to the elements of another Set using Java 7

Tags: java, set

I have 2 sets:

```
Set<String> set1 = new TreeSet<String>();
Set<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>();
Set<String> set3 = new TreeSet<String>();

set1 = [A, C, E];
set2 = [B, D, F];
```

I am looking for a way to append the value of `set2` to `set1` and store them in `set3`

Set 3 Output

```
set3 = [AB, CD, EF]
```

Comment: You can not append elements to a set, because sets do not have a defined order. Do you mean "add" rather than append?

Comment: TreeSet Order its elements. Think of this as adding the entire set as a new column of data to an existing data in another set.

Answer (score 16):

You need to use an `Iterator` to keep the order of the `TreeSet`. You can get it by calling [`TreeSet.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator--):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set in ascending order.

Assuming that both sets have the same length, you could have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set1 = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "C", "E"));
    Set<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList("B", "D", "F"));
    Set<String> set3 = new TreeSet<String>();

    Iterator<String> it1 = set1.iterator();
    Iterator<String> it2 = set2.iterator();
    while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
        set3.add(it1.next() + it2.next());
    }

    System.out.println(set3); // prints "[AB, CD, EF]"
}
```

If the set have different size and that is an error, you could add the following check before the `while` loop:

```
if (set1.size() != set2.size()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't merge sets of different size");
}
```

---

For reference, you could make this using Java 8, using the `zip` utility from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529010/1743880):

```
Set<String> set3 = zip(set1.stream(), set2.stream(), String::concat)
                            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: don't you need to use the LinkedHashSet to preserve the insertion order intact. so when you loop elements are in place where you expect. (where elements this example do fine with treeset)

Comment: @kuhajeyan OP uses a `TreeSet` in their example so I don't think they want to keep insertion order but the natural ordering of the elements.

Comment: @kuhajeyan Actually no! TreeSet is ordered with natural ordering. So using a `LinkedHashSet` or a `TreeSet` in this case makes no difference: we are iterating in the natural ordering of the elements so also adding them in their natural ordering.

Comment: yep, natural ordered.

Comment: Thanks Tunaki, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to do this the imperative way, with **Java 7**:

```
Set<String> set1 = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", "C", "E"}));
Set<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"B", "D", "F"}));
Set<String> set3 = new TreeSet<String>();

// Java 7: imperative
// edit: checking sizes beforehand
if (set1.size() != set2.size()) 
    throw new IllegalStateException("Sets aren't the same size!");
Iterator<String> iterator1 = set1.iterator();
Iterator<String> iterator2 = set2.iterator();
while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator1.next();
    // assuming iterator2.hasNext() as sizes were checked previously
    s = s.concat(iterator2.next());
    set3.add(s);
}
System.out.println(set3);
```

**Output**

```
[AB, CD, EF]
```

**Java 8 variant with functional idiom (a little ugly)**

```
// Java 8: functional (but ugly)
Iterator<String> iterator2new = set2.iterator();
// edited, ensuring a `TreeSet` is returned
set3 = 
    set1
    .stream()
    .map((s) -> s.concat(iterator2new.next()))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
System.out.println(set3);
```

**Output**

```
[AB, CD, EF]
```

Comment: The Java 8 way is not very nice yeah... It does not return a `TreeSet` also. It'd be better to make a proper `zip`. See my answer.

Comment: @Tunaki yes it's ugly and labelled as such... Couldn't find a better way without too many dependencies. Note that you can always wrap it in a `TreeSet` once retrieved though.

Comment: Thanks for providing both answers for Java 8 and 7. What made me chose this answer over Tunaki's is this answers adds the elements until it find a miss match in  size. Where Tunaki's answer will check before it attempts and throw an exception if they are different in size.

Comment: @Moe np. Yes the later check wasn't brilliant but written in the spur of the moment, hence the later `//TODO` :)

Comment: The Java 8 approach is flawed. It suffices that someone call `.parallelStream()` to have weird results. Also there is no need to do `map(o -> o.toString())` as you already have a `Stream<String>` at that point...

Comment: @AlexisC. that's why I don't use `parallelStream()` and call it ugly, but yes you have a point. About the second mapping, not sure why I did this, removing now.

Comment: @BoristheSpider nicer, definitely. Thanks.

Comment: @Mena np. I'm still finding uses for all the `Collectors` provided. My new favourite is [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

Comment: @BoristheSpider interesting. I wish I'd use Java 8 more in real life :(

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use a library that adds `zip` to Java 8 `streams` such as https://github.com/poetix/protonpack or https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL

Answer (score 0):

I quite dislike  `while (it1.hasNext())`, so my ways:

1)

```
    Iterator<String> iterator2 = set2.iterator();
    for(String s : set1) {
            set3.add(s.concat(iterator2.next()));
    }
    System.out.println(set3);
```

2) or

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set2);
    int i = 0;
    for(String s : set1) {
            set3.add(s.concat(list.get(i)));
            i++;
    }
    System.out.println(set3);
```

3) (1) with check:

```
    Iterator<String> iterator2 = set2.iterator();
    for(String s : set1) {
        set3.add(s.concat(iterator2.hasNext()? iterator2.next(): ""));
    }
    System.out.println(set3);
```

4) (2) with check:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set2);
    int i = 0;
    for(String s : set1) {
            set3.add(s.concat(list.size() > i? list.get(i): ""));
            i++;
    }
    System.out.println(set3);
```

Comment: I think this is far less eligible than the `Iterator` based solutions. The suggestion to copy into a `List` just so index access is available is plain horrible.

Comment: It's depends of set size, perfomance doesn't matter for small collection