# Mockito: assertEquals on two lists, comparing object variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, java-8, mockito

I want to use `assertEquals()` on the two lists `list1` and `list2`.

The problem is, that I don't want to compare the lists like `assertEquals(list1, list2)`. The elements are objects that can return their ids with a function `getId()`, and I want to check if the lists are equal in terms of the ids (ordered!).

How can I do that? Is functional programming a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform the lists to lists of ids and then compare them:

```
return list1.stream().map(MyClass::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())
    .equals(list2.stream().map(MyClass::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408290/how-to-compare-equality-of-lists-of-arrays-with-modern-java), so you can take more ideas from there. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35408904/4754790) you can see that in one of the options I proposed is creating a reusable utility method for lists comparison:

```
<T, U> boolean equal(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Function<T, U> mapper) {
    List<U> first = list1.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<U> second = list2.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return first.equals(second);
}
```

Then all you need to write is:

```
return equal(list1, list2, MyClass::getId);
```

Comment: Good idea but what if list elements are in different order?

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun Then they are not equal, of course, as described in the javadoc for `List`s, and that is in line with the requirements in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I marked this one as correct since it is a one liner. Thanks to the other answers, too!

Answer (score 3):

If you create the expected list with the ids of the objects in order, example

```
List<MyObject> expected = new ArrayList<>();
expected.add(myObject1); //with id = 1
expected.add(myObject2); //with id = 2
expected.add(myObject3); //with id = 3

assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

, then if the actual list has objects in different order of ids, it would fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj) fluent assertions library. Your comparison may looks like

```
// "id" need to be either a property or a public field
assertThat(list1).extracting("id").contains(list2);
```

Comment: This would incorrectly assert as true if list1 contains all of the same elements as list2, with some additional ones. If you made that same call one more time but flipping list1/list2 I think that would work as expected (although there are probably better ways to do this).

Answer (score 0):

I see this question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236880/assert-list-in-junit) . If you want to compare the objects only with id , simpler way is to override the equals method , as frameworks use it to assert if two objects are equal.

Comment: In the future, please flag the question as a duplicate, rather than posting an answer saying it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do it directly but instead first compared list size, then compared each element.