# How to update Engine attributes of a List of type Car from a List of type Engine using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of type `Car`

```
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private Engine engine;
    //getters and setters below...
}
```

I would like to update the `Engine` attribute of each `Car` in my `List` from a List of Engines I have. With for-loops I would accomplish this by:

```
if (myListOfCars.size() == myListOfEngines.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myListOfCars.length(); i++) {
         myListOfCars.get(i).setEngine(myListOfEngines.get(i));
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this same logic with Java Streams?

If you have suggestions for a better title please share them.

Comment: is `myListOfCars` and `myListOfEngines` are string?

Comment: because your logic for `length` and `get` method isnt matching..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the `for loop` is a little more readable, but this would do the job, as well.

```
if (myListOfCars.size() == myListOfEngines.size()) {
    IntStream.range(0, myListOfCars.size())
        .forEach(
            i -> myListOfCars.get(i).setEngine(myListOfEngines.get(i)
        )
    );
}
```

Note that I've replaced `.length()` with `.size()` if you copy it.

Comment: Putting the lambda expression on its own line may help with its readability.

Comment: Indeed. Applied some formatting, looks better now hopefully.

Comment: As long as `myListOfCars` and `myListOfEngines` are both of type `ArrayList`, this is will remain acceptable at O(n).  But if either lists are of type `LinkedList`, this would become unnecessarily O(n^2).

Comment: @AJNeufeld: that’s why you shouldn’t use `LinkedList`.

Comment: @Holger, there are use cases where one would prefer LinkedList over ArrayList, e.g. when you mostly rearrange its items instead of accessing them.

Comment: @Matt: I don’t see any valid use case. Since you have to iterate linearly to the particular item each time, even rearranging items with a `LinkedList` is not cheaper than with an `ArrayList`. It would be different with a linked list supporting to keep references to the nodes, but this is not how Java’s `LinkedList` works, where a “structural modification” invalidates all existing list iterators (except for the one you use for the modification).

Comment: @Holger, admitted, considering solely the O-notation for a LinkedList is deceptive and there seem to be much less use cases than one would expect without knowing about the concrete implementation. A last rescue effort, though: regarding a FIFO queue you'd be better off with a LinkedList. ;-)))

Comment: @Matt: Well, if you need a FIFO queue, `ArrayDeque` is the better choice…

Comment: @Holger, but not if you're on Java 1.5 :-)))) Just kiddin... laying down my arms.

Comment: @Holger (picking up Matt's arms) If you get to choose, great.  But what if you don't?  You're given a library / service / interface that passes you a `List<T>`.  Do you a) abuse the stream API to generate a list of integers, for you to use with `List#get(i)`, or b) process the list using an `Iterator<T>` or stream API?  One choice is guaranteed O(n), the other might be, but might be O(n^2).  Choose.  This problem is slightly harder -- traversing 2 lists simultaneously -- but the design decision remains: to guarantee O(n) or not to guarantee O(n).

Comment: @AJNeufeld: either, blame the one who decides to use that list or do roughly the same, JRE methods do: `if( !(list instanceof RandomAccess) && list.size()>threshold) list=new ArrayList<>(list);` before proceeding. Then, the net time complexity is `O(n)`…

Comment: @AJNeufeld: by the way, the OP’s original loop had the same behavior, so we’re not talking about a Stream issue at all.

Comment: @Holger The OP gave an example of what they wanted to accomplish, but wanted to use the Stream API, presumably for conciseness and efficiency.  Using the Stream API to generate loop indices satisfies the letter, not the spirit, of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Zip" the two streams into a stream of pairs.

Unfortunately, there is no [builtin stream zipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip).  But you can make your own, or use one of the suggested libraries.

Then simply apply `(car,engine) -> { car.setEngine(engine); }` to the stream.

Or, as a hack:

```
Iterator<Engine> engine_iter = myListOfEngines.iterator();
myListOfCars.stream().forEach(
     car -> { car.setEngine(engine_iter.next()); }
);
```