# Creating Map composed of 2 Lists using stream().collect in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

As for example, there are two lists:

```
List<Double> list1 = Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0);
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("one_point_zero", "two_point_zero");
```

Using Stream, I want to create a map composed of these lists, where list1 is for keys and list2 is for values. To do it, I need to create an auxiliary list:

```
List<Integer> list0 = Arrays.asList(0, 1);
```

Here is the map:

```
Map<Double, String> map2 = list0.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(list1::get, list2::get));
```

list0 is used in order list1::get and list2::get to work. Is there a simpler way without creation of list0? I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
Map<Double, String> map2 = IntStream
                .iterate(0, e -> e + 1)
                .limit(list1.size())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(list1::get, list2::get));
```

Comment: The answer is found: I should have used Stream.iterate(0, e -> e + 1) instead of IntStream.iterate(0, e -> e + 1)

Comment: so you can close questions

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: No, *don’t* use `Stream.iterate(0, e -> e + 1).limit(list1.size())`. Use `IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).boxed()`. The combination of `iterate` and `limit` has signifcant performance drawbacks compared to a straight-forward `range` stream. And converting an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` is as easy as chaining `boxed()`. You can even avoid boxed `Integer`s entirely: `IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).collect(HashMap::new, (m,i) -> m.put(list1.get(i),list2.get(i)), Map::putAll)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using an auxiliary list to hold the indices, you can have them generated by an `IntStream`.

```
Map<Double, String> map = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> list1.get(i), i -> list2.get(i)));
```

Answer (score 10):

Indeed the best approach is to use [`IntStream.range(startInclusive, endExclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) in order to access to each element of both lists with [`get(index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) and finally use [`Math.min(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) to avoid getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the lists are not of the exact same size, so the final code would be:

```
Map<Double, String> map2 = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(list1::get, list2::get));
```

Comment: While this answer is essentially the same as @svarog's, I like the use of `Math.min` and the `::get` method references (instead of the lambdas) which look cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me but is O(n^2):

```
    Map<Double, String> collect =
            list1.stream()
                    .collect(
                            toMap(Double::doubleValue, 
                                    item -> list2.get(list1.indexOf(item))));
```

Comment: This looks workable, but `indexOf` can be very expensive, especially for long lists and lists with complex values (such as `String`). The two top-rated answers are better.