# Choose between two stream elements given a predicate in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have two Java `Stream<String>` `A` and `B`.

How can I, at each step, given a predicate `p`, pick an element from either `A` or `B`? The element that has not been picked has to stay at the head of the stream so it can be picked at the next try.

Comment: Can you elaborate? for example wich is the criteria for that predicate?

Comment: well, this is somehow unclear. How about an actual example?

Answer (score 1):

Use can use a `zip` method. The standard library doesn't include one as standard, but you can just copy the source shown below (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529010/3141234)).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "a3");
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("b1", "b2", "b3");

        BiFunction<String, String, String> picker = (a, b) -> {
            // pick whether you want a from list1, or b from list2
            return a;
        };

        List<String> result = 
            StreamUtils.zip(list1.stream(), list2.stream(), picker)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

### StreamUtils.java

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class StreamUtils {
    public static<A, B, C> Stream<C> zip(Stream<? extends A> a,
                                         Stream<? extends B> b,
                                         BiFunction<? super A, ? super B, ? extends C> zipper) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(zipper);
        Spliterator<? extends A> aSpliterator = Objects.requireNonNull(a).spliterator();
        Spliterator<? extends B> bSpliterator = Objects.requireNonNull(b).spliterator();

        // Zipping looses DISTINCT and SORTED characteristics
        int characteristics = aSpliterator.characteristics() & bSpliterator.characteristics() &
                ~(Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.SORTED);

        long zipSize = ((characteristics & Spliterator.SIZED) != 0)
                ? Math.min(aSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(), bSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown())
                : -1;

        Iterator<A> aIterator = Spliterators.iterator(aSpliterator);
        Iterator<B> bIterator = Spliterators.iterator(bSpliterator);
        Iterator<C> cIterator = new Iterator<C>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return aIterator.hasNext() && bIterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public C next() {
                return zipper.apply(aIterator.next(), bIterator.next());
            }
        };

        Spliterator<C> split = Spliterators.spliterator(cIterator, zipSize, characteristics);
        return (a.isParallel() || b.isParallel())
               ? StreamSupport.stream(split, true)
               : StreamSupport.stream(split, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no sense in a construct like `Objects.requireNonNull(a).spliterator()`. All `requireNonNull` does, is throwing a `NullPointerException` if `a` is `null`, which is what happens anyway, when you just call `a.spliterator()`. Further, you can use `long zipSize = Math.min(aSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(), bSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown());` as it will be `-1` anyway, if either stream has no `SIZED` property. And the return statement can be simplified to `return StreamSupport.stream(split, a.isParallel() || b.isParallel());`, no need for an additional conditional expression.

Comment: @Holger This is code copied from the answer I linked in my question. Apparently it was originally taken from the JDK source before this API was made private in the 1.8 release.

Comment: What do you mean with “before this API was made private”? Do you claim there was a secret `zip` method within the JDK? Besides that, everyone copying abandoned code must be aware that (s)he is now the new maintainer.

Comment: By the way, this code does not fulfill the OP’s requirement, “*The element that has not been picked has to stay at the head of the stream so it can be picked at the next try.*”

Comment: @Holger Yes, there is such an API. It's [`Streams.zip`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b93/docs/api/java/util/stream/Streams.html), which was public in b93, but is now private in 1.8.

Comment: I don’t question that there was such a method in beta93, I question your claim that it is “now private”. It has been *removed*, which is a different thing than making something `private`. There is no `zip` method anymore.

Comment: Iirc, trying to use it gave me an error about it's access level. I think the `Streams` class as a whole has package access.

Comment: There is a non-`public` class with that name, but it has no `zip` method. After removing the `zip` method and moving the `concat` methods to the `Stream` interfaces, there was nothing left that would justify keeping this class `public`.

Comment: @Holger Okay, so it was deleted, not made private. Not sure where you're going with that

Answer (score 0):

If the two input streams are already sorted by the merge function, the new stream will be sorted by the merge function eventually. It's going to be something like merge sort. So you just need to concat the two streams, sorted then.

```
final Stream<String> a = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
final Stream<String> b = Stream.of("1", "2", "3");        
Stream.concat(a, b).sorted((a, b) -> mergeFunction /* TODO */);
```

Otherwise, probably you will need the stream API in [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common):

```
final Stream<String> a = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
final Stream<String> b = Stream.of("1", "2", "3");        
Stream.merge(a, b, mergeFunction);
```