# Using Java 8 streams for aggregating list objects

Tags: java-8

We are using 3 lists ListA,ListB,ListC to keep the marks for 10 students in 3 subjects (A,B,C).

Subject B and C are optional, so only few students out of 10 have marks in those subjects

```
Class Student{
String studentName;
int marks;
}
```

ListA has records for 10 students, ListB for 5 and ListC for 3 (which is also the size of the lists)

Want to know how we can sum up the marks of the students for their subjects using java 8 steam.

I tried the following

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0,listA.size() -1).mapToObj(i -> listA.get(i).getMarks() + 
listB.get(i).getMarks() + 
listC.get(i).getMarks()).collect(Collectors.toList());;
```

There are 2 issues with this

a) It will give IndexOutOfBoundsException as listB and listC don't have 10 elements

b) The returned list if of type Integer and I want it to be of type Student.

Any inputs will be very helpful

Comment: So, a Subject is, in fact, a Student, with its mark in one subject, right? The name is the name of the student, right?

Comment: I think you need zipping for that, frankly zipping isn't in the standard library !! see here for how to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: Yes, it is a Student..i have corrected the details. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a stream of the 3 lists and then call `flatMap` to put all the lists' elements into a single stream. That stream will contain one element per student per mark, so you will have to aggregate the result by student name. Something along the lines of:

```
Map<String, Integer> studentMap = Stream.of(listA, listB, listC)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(student -> student.name, summingInt(student -> student.mark)));
```

Alternatively, if your `Student` class has getters for its fields, you can change the last line to make it more readable:

```
Map<String, Integer> studentMap = Stream.of(listA, listB, listC)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(Student::getName, summingInt(Student::getMark)));
```

Then check the result by printing out the `studentMap`:

```
studentMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " - " + value));
```

If you want to create a list of `Student` objects instead, you can use the result of the first map and create a new stream from its entries (this particular example assumes your `Student` class has an all-args constructor so you can one-line it):

```
List<Student> studentList = Stream.of(listA, listB, listC)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(Student::getName, summingInt(Student::getMark)))
        .entrySet().stream()
            .map(mapEntry -> new Student(mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue()))
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Good answer. The list of lists approach is flexible in that it can accommodate any number of mandatory and optional subjects. If `listA`, `listB` and `listC` are hardcoded, one may alternatively use two invocations of `Stream.concat()` for concatenating three streams into one.

Comment: @OleV.V.  Stream.of(T... values) is any other option for 3 or more lists. `Stream.of(listA, listb, listc).flatMap(Collection::stream). ...`

Comment: Instead of returning Map<String, Integer> how can i return Map<String, Student> where Student object . mark will have the summed mark?

Comment: As far as I know, once you call `collect` on a stream, the stream is finished, so you can't do this all in one stream. You can, however, chain the calls together. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to incorporate the suggestion from @ÖmerErden and also to include a possible solution for returning a `List<Student>`. You can easily change this to a `Map<String, Student>` by replacing the last line with `collect(toMap(Student::getName, student -> student))` if that's more useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

```
Map<String, Student> result = Stream.of(listA, listB, listC)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Student::getName, // key: student's name
        s -> new Student(s.getName(), s.getMarks()), // value: new Student
        (s1, s2) -> { // merge students with same name: sum marks
            s1.setMarks(s1.getMarks() + s2.getMarks());
            return s1;
        }));
```

Here I've used [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to create the map (I've also assumed you have a constructor for `Student` that receives a name and marks).

This version of `Collectors.toMap` expects three arguments:

1. A function that returns the key for each element (here it's `Student::getName`)
2. A function that returns the value for each element (I've created a new `Student` instance that is a copy of the original element, this is to not modify instances from the original stream)
3. A merge function that is to be used when there are elements that have the same key, i.e. for students with the same name (I've summed the marks here).

If you could add the following copy constructor and method to your `Student` class:

```
public Student(Student another) {
    this.name = another.name;
    this.marks = another.marks;
}

public Student merge(Student another) {
    this.marks += another.marks;
    return this;
}
```

Then you could rewrite the code above in this way:

```
Map<String, Student> result = Stream.of(listA, listB, listC)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Student::getName,
        Student::new,
        Student::merge));
```

Comment: I agree, this is a more efficient way to do it than my solution. I recommend marking this as accepted answer, @girish .

Comment: There are pros and cons. I don’t like you modifying the objects from the original lists. The asker will have to weigh this against the advantages.

Comment: @OleV.V. In the first snippet the original objects are not modified

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, I believe the call `s1.setMarks(s1.getMarks() + s2.getMarks())` modifies the `Student` object `s1`, and that this object comes from the original stream. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @OleV.V. Now I get what you mean. I will update the answer to fix this, thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: @OleV.V. Updated the answer as per your comment, thanks again