# Creating a lambda function to iterate collections simultaneously

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying Java 8, I want to iterate over 2 collections and call a parameter function for each pair of values.

In abstract, I want to apply a `foo(tuple, i)` function for each iteration

```
[ v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 ] (first collection)
[ w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6 ] (second collection)
---------------------------
  foo(<v1,w1>, 0)
  foo(<v2,w2>, 1)
  ...
  foo(<v6,w6>, 5)
```

---

Now what I got so far (java and pseudo code)

```
// Type of f?
private <S,U> void iterateSimultaneously(Collection<S> c1, Collection<U> c2, Function f) {
        int i = 0
        Iterator<S> it1 = c1.iterator()
        Iterator<U> it2 = c2.iterator()
        while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
            Tuple<S, U> tuple = new Tuple<>(it1.next(), it2.next())             

            // call somehow f(tuple, i)

            i++
        }
}
 // ........................

// pseudo code, is this posible in Java?
iterateSimultaneously(c1, c2, (e1, e2, i) -> {
  // play with those items and the i value
})
```

Comment: What does the comment `// Type of f?` mean? What are `e1, e2, i`?

Comment: Are all collections iterated over going to be the same size, or should different sizes be handled?

Comment: Take a look at stream "zipping": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: It’s funny, how often people on Stackoverflow need to iterate two collections simultaneously while I never encountered that task in real life.

Comment: @Aaron Let's say they have the same size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
private <S,U> void iterateSimultaneously(Collection<S> c1, Collection<U> c2, BiConsumer<Tuple<S, U>, Integer> f) {
        int i = 0
        Iterator<S> it1 = c1.iterator()
        Iterator<U> it2 = c2.iterator()
        while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
            Tuple<S, U> tuple = new Tuple<>(it1.next(), it2.next())             
            f.accept(tuple, i);
            i++
        }
}
iterateSimultaneously(c1, c2, (t, i) -> {
    //stuff
})
```

What type is the function f supposed to return? If nothing, change it to a consumer instead. If you want it to accept a tuple you most clarify it like I have done here. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [a `BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html):

```
private <S,U> void iterateSimultaneously(Collection<S> c1, Collection<U> c2,
                                         BiConsumer<Tuple<S, U>, Integer> f) {

  f.accept(tuple, i);
}
```

and call it with:

```
iterateSimultaneously(c1, c2, (tuple, i) -> doSomethingWith(tuple, i));
```

The signature of `doSomethingWith` would look like:

```
private <S, U> void doSomethingWith(Tuple<S, U> tuple, int i) {

}
```

Comment: That looks great, but I fail to see how it works. Also those `tuple` and `i` var in `iterateSimultaneously` doesn't seem to correspond to anything ?

Comment: @Aaron not sure I understand your question.

Comment: You write `f.accept(tuple, i);` in your first snippet, but I fail to see how `tuple` and `i` are defined in this scope.

Comment: What is this `Tuple` class?

Comment: @user1803551 it's just a `Pair` or a Holder for two values; like a `Map.Entry`

Comment: @Aaron They are defined in the code posted in the question,

Answer (score 2):

You can find an detailed implementation using Stream API of Java 8 of what you are looking for just here (the method `zip()`) : 
https://github.com/JosePaumard/streams-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/paumard/streams/StreamsUtils.java#L398

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Guava's utilities for streams, particularly [`Streams.zip`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`Streams.mapWithIndex`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#mapWithIndex-java.util.stream.DoubleStream-com.google.common.collect.Streams.DoubleFunctionWithIndex-). You might use them both to achieve what you want:

```
Collection<Double> numbers = Arrays.asList(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5);
Collection<String> letters = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

Stream<Tuple<Double, String>> zipped = Streams.zip(
    numbers.stream(),
    letters.stream(),
    Tuple::new);

Stream<String> withIndex = Streams.mapWithIndex(
    zipped, 
    (tuple, index) -> index + ": " + tuple.u + "/" + tuple.v);

withIndex.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This produces the following output:

```
0: 1.1/a
1: 2.2/b
2: 3.3/c
3: 4.4/d
4: 5.5/e
```

This works by first zipping streams for `c1` and `c2` collections into one `zipped` stream of tuples and then mapping this zipped stream with a function that receives both each tuple and its corresponding index.

---

Note that `Streams.mapWithIndex` must receive a `BiFunction`, which means that it must return a value. If you want to consume both the tuples and the indices instead, I'm afraid you will need to create a new tuple containing the original tuple and the index:

```
Stream<Tuple<Tuple<Double, String>, Long>> withIndex = Streams.mapWithIndex(
    zipped,
    Tuple::new);

withIndex.forEach(tuple -> someMethod(tuple.u, tuple.v));
```

Where `someMethod` has the following signature:

```
<U, V> void method(Tuple<U, V> tuple, long index)
```

Note 1: this example assumes the following `Tuple` class is used:

```
public class Tuple<U, V> {
    private final U u;
    private final V v;

    Tuple(U u, V v) {
        this.u = u;
        this.v = v;
    }

    // TODO: getters and setters, hashCode and equals
}
```

Note 2: while you can achieve the same with iterators, the main advantage of these utilities is that they also work efficiently on parallel streams.

Note 3: this functionality is available since Guava 21.0.