# Merging/consuming multiple Java 8 streams into one stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I have two streams:

```
Stream<String> ids = Stream.of("id1","id2","id3","id4","id5");
Stream<MyObj> objects = Stream.of(new MyObj(null, "some data"), new MyObj(null, "some other data");
```

Now I would like to update my `objects` stream with the data from `ids`. The result whould be equivalent to the following Stream:

```
Stream<MyObj> objects = Stream.of(new MyObj("id1", "some data"), new MyObj("id2", "some other data");
```

I thus wonder if there is a way to consume both streams, one element at the time. I imagine some kind of "DoubleConsumer" (nothing to do with `double`) of the sort:

```
Stream<MyObj> result = DoubleConsumer.of(ids, objects)
                          .map((id, myobj) -> combine(id, myobj));

MyObj combine(String id, MyObj myobj) {
  myobj.set(id);
  return myobj;
}
```

Any idea how to achieve something like this?

***Update***

I know that I can solve this in the case of list with some double loop, or with FuncionalJava's `zip`function. However the question is how to do this with Java Streams.

Comment: Why is it a double consumer? You are using new in your second example?

Comment: can you use a loop and plain lists?

Comment: Can new MyObj instances be created instead of updating old ones?

Comment: @agnul, there is no answer in question you linked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: @Basilevs No problem if it's new instances.

Comment: Then matt's answer looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want Stream.map. eg.

```
Stream<MyObj> objs = ids.map(id->new MyObj(id, "some data"));
```

This does exactly what op wants. Then if they want to update the values of the objects they can afterwards, and the objects know their id so that can be gotten.

If they want to "zip" two streams, they should check the existing answers.