# How can I return 2-dimensional array in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a method that returns a matrix, where row is a pair of `User` and `MessageData`.

```
public static Object[][] getData() {
    DomXmlParsing parse = new DomXmlParsing();
    List<User> users = parse.getUsers();
    List<MessageData> datas = parse.getDataForMessage();
    return new Object[][]{
            {users.get(0), datas.get(0)},
            {users.get(1), datas.get(1)},
            {users.get(2), datas.get(2)},
            {users.get(3), datas.get(3)},
            {users.get(4), datas.get(4)}
    };
}
```

How can I return this matrix using Stream API of Java 8?

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 4).map(i -> new Object[]{users.get(i), datas.get(i)}).toArray(Object[][]::new)`

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip#23529010

Comment: If you can use Guava, there's [`Streams.zip`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function.

Comment: Poor question title. You should mention streams in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish the task at hand with:

```
return IntStream.range(0, users.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> new Object[]{users.get(i), datas.get(i)})
                .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```