# merge streams to produce alternating sequence using lambda or Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, sequence, alternating

I have some code which returns a Stream as intended, but maybe it can be replaced with some type of lambda or stream() operation instead of exhausting the iterators in a `while` loop?

It is just a method that alternates elements from the streams `first` and `second` and stops when one of them runs out of elements.

```
public static <T>Stream<T> alternatingSequence(Stream<T> first, Stream<T> second){
        Iterator<T> iteratorFirst = first.iterator();
        Iterator<T> iteratorSecond = second.iterator();
        Stream<T> resultStream = Stream.empty();
        while (iteratorFirst.hasNext() && iteratorSecond.hasNext()){
            resultStream = Stream.concat(resultStream, Stream.of(iteratorFirst.next(), iteratorSecond.next()));
        }
        return resultStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you also include what this code is supposed to do, instead of leaving it to the reader to figure that.

Comment: Are you alternating the two iterators?

Comment: Using Java Stream API. Maybe, this code can't be replaced lambda expression?

Comment: Just method that alternates elements from the streams first and second and stopping when one of them runs out of elements

Comment: ah, so you intend to combine two streams (a1,a2...) and (b1,b2...) and return _alternating_ (a1, b1, a2, b2...) ? and presumably you want lazy-evaluation of next elements, am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Comment: @PatrickParker Changed that long ago.

Comment: Something like `Stream.generate(() -> null).takewhile(iteratorFirst.hasNext() && iteratorSecond.hasNext()).flatMap(ignored -> Stream.of(iteratorFirst.next(), iteratorSecond.next()))` could do, but I don't think it's more readable than your existing solution.

Comment: Or `StreamSupport.stream(iteratorFirst.spliterator(), false).filter(element -> iteratorSecond.hasNext()).flatMap(element -> Stream.of(element, iteratorSecond.next()))` but it again violates the contract, as the `Predicate` should be stateless.

Comment: I must use Java8 only, so "takeWhile" is not valid method for me. How can I replace it by Java8?

Comment: @Сергей What exactly is the output you require?

Comment: Stream first["A", "B", "C", "D"], Stream second["1", "2", "3"], Stream output["A", "1", "B", "2", "C", "3"], for example.

Comment: @Сергей was your question answered successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Guava's Streams.zip](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) you can combine the two streams into a stream of two-element streams, which you may then simply flatten to produce an alternating sequence:

```
return Streams.zip(first, second, (arg1, arg2) -> Stream.of(arg1, arg2))
    .flatMap(Function.identity());
```

One caveat is that the resulting stream is not efficiently splittable (see linked doc). This may harm parallel performance.

**Note:**

If you don't have access to Guava then you can implement your own `zip(a, b, bifunc)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529010/7098259).