# Java8: Stream merge two lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists

```
List1 - (1, 2, 3)
List2 - (4, 5, 6,7, 8)
```

Want to merge both the list as  `(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8)` using java streams

First element from List1, List2 and, Second element from list1, list2 ...so on..if any extra elements remain then place at the end.

Comment: `List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>(firstList); l1.addAll(secondOne)`

Comment: `Stream.of(list1, list2)
          .flatMap(List::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: I think, merge in required order simplier without using streams

Answer (score 13):

```
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Maxim - thanks for the response but that will print as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 means all from stream1 then stream2  but required as first element from list1, list2 and, second element from list1, list2  ...so on..if any extra elements ..then place at the end.

Comment: Oh, my fault. Sorry. Please look through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51385350/6075655

Answer (score 0):

Other answer has a link to a working solution, but here's another approach:

```
    List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

    List<Integer> combined = IntStream.range(0, Math.max(l1.size(), l2.size()))
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> {
                if (i < Math.min(l1.size(), l2.size()))
                    return Stream.of(l1.get(i), l2.get(i));
                else if (i < l1.size())
                    return Stream.of(l1.get(i));
                return Stream.of(l2.get(i));
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(combined);
```

Answer (score -4):

using java streams you can do it easily.
List1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).addAll(List2);