# How to interleave (merge) two Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

```
 Stream<String> a = Stream.of("one", "three", "five");
 Stream<String> b = Stream.of("two", "four", "six");
```

What do I need to do for the output to be the below?

```
// one
// two
// three
// four
// five
// six
```

I looked into `concat` but as the javadoc explains, it just appends one after the other, it does not interleave / intersperse.

```
Stream<String> out = Stream.concat(a, b);
out.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> Creates a lazily concatenated stream whose elements are all the
>        elements of the first stream followed by all the elements of the
>        second stream.

Wrongly gives

```
 // one
 // three
 // five
 // two
 // four
 // six
```

Could do it if I collected them and iterated, but was hoping for something more Java8-y, Streamy :-)

**Note**

I don't want to zip the streams

> “zip” operation will take an element from each collection and combine them.

the result of a zip operation would be something like this: (unwanted)

```
 // onetwo
 // threefour
 // fivesix
```

Comment: zip is used to combine elements, I don't want to combine the elements, I want to keep the same total number of elements

Comment: why wouldn't zip keep the same total number of elements?

Comment: Reading the other thread, zip always takes a zipper function to combine an element from each stream to make a new element. I just want to interleave not zip

Comment: I see your point and thanks for the clarification, using the `zip` function from the aforementioned dupe one could do `Stream<String> result = zip(a, b, (e, z) -> Stream.of(e, z)).flatMap(x -> x);` to get the result you want above.

Comment: yeah thanks, thats what I've done. Just a shame that zip question is so so noisy, and doesn't come up when you google the keywords I've used here

Comment: For anyone coming here in the future, here is the comments + redirected answer : https://gist.github.com/blundell/3f062b8ec55fd1906c68e6ec8d848683

Comment: I like the creation of the `interleave` method which essentially wraps the `zip` method to improve readability et al. I've voted to reopen, so you could post that here instead of externally...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I’d use something like this:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> interleave(Stream<? extends T> a, Stream<? extends T> b) {
    Spliterator<? extends T> spA = a.spliterator(), spB = b.spliterator();
    long s = spA.estimateSize() + spB.estimateSize();
    if(s < 0) s = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    int ch = spA.characteristics() & spB.characteristics()
           & (Spliterator.NONNULL|Spliterator.SIZED);
    ch |= Spliterator.ORDERED;

    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(s, ch) {
        Spliterator<? extends T> sp1 = spA, sp2 = spB;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            Spliterator<? extends T> sp = sp1;
            if(sp.tryAdvance(action)) {
                sp1 = sp2;
                sp2 = sp;
                return true;
            }
            return sp2.tryAdvance(action);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

It retains the characteristics of the input streams as far as possible, which allows certain optimizations (e.g. for `count()`and `toArray()`). Further, it adds the `ORDERED` even when the input streams might be unordered, to reflect the interleaving.

When one stream has more elements than the other, the remaining elements will appear at the end.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `Stream<? extends T> a` for a much generic solution? Just asking, since I referenced this in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58776334/1746118).

Comment: @Naman of course. It's just a bit annoying having to carry the `? extends` throughout the entire code. But it should be done for a good API.

Answer (score 2):

A much dumber solution than Holger did, but may be it would fit your requirements:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> interleave(Stream<T> left, Stream<T> right) {
    Spliterator<T> splLeft = left.spliterator();
    Spliterator<T> splRight = right.spliterator();

    T[] single = (T[]) new Object[1];

    Stream.Builder<T> builder = Stream.builder();

    while (splRight.tryAdvance(x -> single[0] = x) && splLeft.tryAdvance(builder)) {
        builder.add(single[0]);
    }

    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: This inconsistently includes all elements of `left`, when it has more elements than `right`, but will drop elements of `right` when it has more than `left`. You should decide. To included all common elements, use `do {} while(splLeft.tryAdvance(builder) && spRight.tryAdvance(builder));`, then decide. If you want to include all elements when the the streams have different sizes, do `(splLeft.tryAdvance(builder)? splLeft: spRight).forEachRemaining(builder);` after the loop. And well, `Stream.Builder<T>` does already implement `Consumer<T>`, conveniently.

Comment: @Holger indeed i wanted only common ones, but now the problem is worse, since  `do {} while(splLeft.tryAdvance(builder) && spRight.tryAdvance(builder));` will still take an element from `left`, so it's still not correct :(. the bigger problem I see now that I think about it - is that this is cheating, `Stream.Builder` still uses a hidden collection to gather elements...

Comment: Taking one additional element from left wouldn’t contradict the “interleaving” pattern (ababa). If you don’t want that, consider tracking the count and apply a `limit` to the resulting stream. That’s simpler than dealing with an *additional* storage operation, especially with generic arrays. The builder implies a storage, I thought you were aware of it, as that’s the main (only) disadvantage over implementing a spliterator.

Comment: @Holger I thought about a `limit` too, but don't know, the more I think about it, the more I like what you did

Comment: To rescue your approach, how about `for(List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<>(1); splRight.tryAdvance(tmp::add) && splLeft.tryAdvance(builder); tmp.clear()) tmp.forEach(builder);`?

Comment: @Holger I admit I was working into something close to that, but your solution is far more nice. thank you for the time, still your solution (as usual) must be the accepted one.

Comment: Streams may contain `null`, so you shouldn’t use a test against `null` here. On the other hand, there is no reason not to use the return value of `splRight.tryAdvance(…)`, you can even inline the call into the `if` statement. It also makes the `single[0] = null;` obsolete. Then, transform the `while(true) { if(condition) { statement; continue; } break; }` to a `while(condition) statement;`…

Comment: Another con is that this approach is not lazy, i.e. it constructs the builder for the new interleaved stream in memory...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner right, that is the exact point about the in memory collection, overall, just use whatever Holger put in place...

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the question comments, I gave this a go using zip:

```
Stream<String> a = Stream.of("one", "three", "five");
Stream<String> b = Stream.of("two", "four", "six");

Stream<String> out = interleave(a, b);


    public static <T> Stream<T> interleave(Stream<T> streamA, Stream<T> streamB) {
        return zip(streamA, streamB, (o1, o2) -> Stream.of(o1, o2)).flatMap(s -> s);
    }

    /**
    * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip
    **/
    private static <A, B, C> Stream<C> zip(Stream<A> streamA, Stream<B> streamB, BiFunction<A, B, C> zipper) {
        final Iterator<A> iteratorA = streamA.iterator();
        final Iterator<B> iteratorB = streamB.iterator();
        final Iterator<C> iteratorC = new Iterator<C>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return iteratorA.hasNext() && iteratorB.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public C next() {
                return zipper.apply(iteratorA.next(), iteratorB.next());
            }
        };
        final boolean parallel = streamA.isParallel() || streamB.isParallel();
        return iteratorToFiniteStream(iteratorC, parallel);
    }

    private static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToFiniteStream(Iterator<T> iterator, boolean parallel) {
        final Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), parallel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may **not** be a good answer because
(1) it collects to map, which you don't want to do I guess and
(2) it is not completely stateless as it uses AtomicIntegers.

Still adding it because
(1) it is readable and
(2) community can get an idea from this and try to improve it.

```
Stream<String> a = Stream.of("one", "three", "five");
Stream<String> b = Stream.of("two", "four", "six");

AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger j = new AtomicInteger(1);

Stream.of(a.collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> i.addAndGet(2), Function.identity())),
        b.collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> j.addAndGet(2), Function.identity())))
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getValue())); // or collect
```

**Output**

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

**@Holger's edit**

```
Stream.concat(a.map(o -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i.addAndGet(2), o)),
        b.map(o -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(j.addAndGet(2), o)))
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getValue())); // or collect
```

Comment: You don’t need to collect into maps, as you are only interested in getting the stream of entries, so you can simply use `Stream.concat( a.map(o -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i.addAndGet(2),o)),  b.map(o -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(j.addAndGet(2),o))  )` to get it. Then, you may chain `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())`. But you’re right in that this mutable state is discouraged. Most notably, it will have problems with parallel execution.

Comment: @Holger thank you, added this to the answer. I thought about it earlier, but couldn't find an `EntrySet` constructor and got lazy to google search how to create an EntrySet :(

Comment: It’s not creating an `EntrySet` but just a stream of `Entry` instances. The ready-to-use implementations are indeed not easy to find (there’s also a `SimpleImmutableEntry` in `AbstractMap`). Starting with Java 9, you can simply use `Map.entry(key, value)` to get an immutable `Entry` instance, but you have to be aware that it does not support `null` keys or values, so you can only use it when you can preclude `null`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `Iterator`

```
final Iterator<String> iterA = a.iterator();
final Iterator<String> iterB = b.iterator();

final Iterator<String> iter = new Iterator<String>() {
  private final AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger();
  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() { 
    return iterA.hasNext() || iterB.hasNext();
  }
  @Override
  public String next() {
    return idx.getAndIncrement() % 2 == 0 && iterA.hasNext() ? iterA.next() : iterB.next();
  }
};

 // Create target Stream with StreamEx from: https://github.com/amaembo/streamex    
 StreamEx.of(iter).forEach(System.out::println);

 // Or Streams from Google Guava
 Streams.stream(iter).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or simply by the solution in [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common) provided by me:

```
 AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger();
 StreamEx.merge(a, b, (s1, s2) -> idx.getAndIncrement() % 2 == 0 ? Nth.FIRST : Nth.SECOND).forEach(Fn.println());
```

Answer (score 1):

without any external lib (using jdk11)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MergeUtil {

    private static <T> Stream<T> zipped(List<T> lista, List<T> listb) {
        int maxSize = Math.max(lista.size(), listb.size());
        final var listStream = IntStream
                .range(0, maxSize)
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(2);
                    if (i < lista.size()) result.add(lista.get(i));
                    if (i < listb.size()) result.add(listb.get(i));
                    return result;
                });
        return listStream.flatMap(List::stream);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var l1 = List.of(1, 2, 3);
        var l2 = List.of(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        final var zip = zipped(l1, l2);
        System.out.println(zip.collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

}
```

listStream is a `Stream<List<A>>` that flatted in return.

The result is:
`[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any hammer. For each element of the first stream, construct a stream with that element and an element of the second (extracted with an iterator), then flatMap:

```
Stream<String> a = Stream.of("one", "three", "five");
Stream<String> b = Stream.of("two", "four", "six");
Iterator<String> bi = b.iterator();
a.flatMap( x -> Stream.of(x, bi.next()) ).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Guava's [Streams.zip](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/28.1-jre/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and `Stream.flatMap`:

```
Stream<String> interleaved = Streams
        .zip(a, b, (x, y) -> Stream.of(x, y))
        .flatMap(Function.identity());
```

---

```
interleaved.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```