# Find the longest Path common to two Paths in Java

Tags: java, file

If I have two Paths, how can I find the longest common Path of the two?

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Path common(Path pathA, Path pathB) {
    ...
}
...
common(Paths.get("/a/b/c/d/e"), Paths.get("/a/b/c/g/h"))
```

Expected output:

```
Paths.get("/a/b/c")
```

Comment: Do you want to find longest common prefix? Or any longest common subpath?

Comment: You could split the strings and compare the parts in between the "/". In the end return the correct substring.

Comment: @MichałZiober the longest common prefix. It should find the nearest parent directory that is common to both paths.

Answer (score 4):

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("/a/b/c/d/e");
Path path2 = Paths.get("/a/b/c/g/h");
```

You can relativize the paths to one another:

```
Path relativePath = path1.relativize(path2).normalize();
// result: ../../g/h
```

and then go to the parent until the path ends in `..`

```
while(relativePath != null && !relativePath.endsWith("..")) {
    relativePath = relativePath.getParent();
}
// result: ../.. (but may also be null)
```

the result can be applied back to any of the two paths:

```
Path result = path1.resolve(relativePath).normalize()
// result: /a/b/c
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple idea

```
    Path a = Paths.get("a/b/c/d/e");
    Path b = Paths.get("a/b/c/g/h");

    // Normalize
    a = a.normalize();
    b = b.normalize();

    // Create common root
    Path common = null;
    if (a.isAbsolute() && b.isAbsolute() && a.getRoot().equals(b.getRoot())) {
            common = a.getRoot();
    }
    else if (!a.isAbsolute() && !b.isAbsolute()) {
            common = Paths.get("");
    }

    // Iterate from root until names differ
    if (common != null) {
            int n = Math.min(a.getNameCount(), b.getNameCount());
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                    if (a.getName(i).equals(b.getName(i))) {
                            common = common.resolve(a.getName(i));
                    }
                    else {
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }

    // Show
    System.out.println(common);
```

Comment: This looks good, except if you use absolute paths "/a/b/c" you'll get back relative path "a/b/c".

Comment: You might want to add a `getRoot()` call.

Comment: Thanks @DodgyCodeException, I have added code to support both cases.

Comment: Now it works well on Linux, but not on Windows ("C:\a\b", "D:\f\g" -> "\" ?)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, Nice catch. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can generate all subpaths starting from the longest possible and check which two are equal:

```
private Path commonPath(Path path0, Path path1) {
    if (path0.equals(path1)) {
        return path0;
    }

    path0 = path0.normalize();
    path1 = path1.normalize();
    int minCount = Math.min(path0.getNameCount(), path1.getNameCount());
    for (int i = minCount; i > 0; i--) {
        Path sp0 = path0.subpath(0, i);
        if (sp0.equals(path1.subpath(0, i))) {
            String root = Objects.toString(path0.getRoot(), "");
            return Paths.get(root, sp0.toString());
        }
    }

    return path0.getRoot();
}
```

And usage:

```
Map<String, String> paths = new LinkedHashMap<>();
paths.put("/a/b/c", "/a/b/d");
paths.put("/a/", "/a/b/d");
paths.put("/f/b/c", "/a/b/d");
paths.put("/a/b/c/d/e", "/a/b/f/../c/g");
paths.put("C:/Winnt/System32", "C:/Winnt/System64");

paths.forEach((k, v) ->
        System.out.println(
                k + " = " + v + " => " + commonPath(Paths.get(k), Paths.get(v))));
```

Above code prints:

```
/a/b/c = /a/b/d => /a/b
/a/ = /a/b/d => /a
/f/b/c = /a/b/d => /
/a/b/c/d/e = /a/b/f/../c/g => /a/b/c
C:/Winnt/System32 = C:/Winnt/System64 => C:/Winnt
```

Comment: You might want to add a `getRoot()` call to fix the problem of stripping the initial "/".

Comment: Good catch. Thanks! I updated answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the question, it's always fun trying to answer using streams:

```
public static Path commonPath(Path a, Path b) {
    Path other = b.normalize();
    return Stream.iterate(a.normalize(), Path::getParent)
        .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(parent -> Stream.iterate(other, Path::getParent).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
                                .anyMatch(x -> Objects.equals(x, parent)))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

This works on Windows / Linux, for example try the test data in @Michał Ziober answer. This just iterates up the parent hierarchy of first until it meets a parent of the other.

With the suggestion by Bass in comments, the common path check is more concise using the other version of `Stream.iterate`:

```
public static Path commonPath(Path a, Path b) {
    return Stream.iterate(a.normalize(), Objects::nonNull, Path::getParent)
        .filter(parent -> Stream.iterate(b.normalize(), Objects::nonNull, Path::getParent)
                                .anyMatch(parent::equals))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

A small refactoring could pull out `Stream.iterate(path.normalize(), Objects::nonNull, Path::getParent)` to a new method `Stream<Path> parentsOf(Path path)` as it is repeated twice above.

Comment: Great answer!

I can only comment that the 3-argument form of `Stream.iterate()` can be used in both cases, e.g.: `Stream.iterate(a.normalize(), Objects::nonNull, Path::getParent)`.

Answer (score 0):

While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70381752/1343979) by [DuncG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4712734/duncg) is definitely the most concise and probably the most efficient one, I'll add my solution, too.

Consider we have a function to transform a `Path` into a `Stream` of path entries:

```java
@NonNull Stream<@NonNull Path> pathEntries(final @NonNull Path path) {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.ofNullable(path.getRoot()), StreamSupport.stream(path.spliterator(), false));
}
```

Now, consider we have another helper function that [zips two streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43059312/1343979) together (e.g.: `Streams.zip()` from *Guava*):

```java
<A, B, R> @NonNull Stream<R> zip(
        final @NonNull Stream<A> streamA,
        final @NonNull Stream<B> streamB,
        final BiFunction<? super A, ? super B, ? extends R> function
) {
    final Spliterator<A> splitrA = streamA.spliterator();
    final Spliterator<B> splitrB = streamB.spliterator();
    final int characteristics = splitrA.characteristics()
            & splitrB.characteristics()
            & (Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.ORDERED);
    final Iterator<A> itrA = Spliterators.iterator(splitrA);
    final Iterator<B> itrB = Spliterators.iterator(splitrB);
    return StreamSupport.stream(new AbstractSpliterator<R>(Math.min(splitrA.estimateSize(), splitrB.estimateSize()), characteristics) {
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(final @NonNull Consumer<? super R> action) {
            if (itrA.hasNext() && itrB.hasNext()) {
                action.accept(function.apply(itrA.next(), itrB.next()));
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }, false)
            .onClose(streamA::close)
            .onClose(streamB::close);
}
```

Then, the solution will look like this:

```java
@Nullable Path commonOrNull(final @NonNull Path left, final @NonNull Path right) {
    return zip(
            pathEntries(left.normalize()),
            pathEntries(right.normalize()),
            (l, r) -> l.equals(r) ? l : null
    )
            .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
            .reduce(Path::resolve)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

This will also work on *Windows*, returning `null` for any two paths that don't share a common file system root, like `C:\foo` and `D:\foo`.