# Explicitely use UnixPath or WindowsPath in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, nio

I want to test a method with finds the longest, common subpath of two Paths ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596369/2021763)).
As the program should run under Windows and Linux, I want to create tests with Linux paths and other tests with Windows paths.

The problem is, that the Windows tests only pass in a Windows environment and fail in a Linux environment.
For the Linux tests it is the other way around.

I can mitigate the problem by checking the OS before doing the actual test. e.g.: `org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(isWindows());`
But then the tests always pass in our Jenkins instance, which is run on Linux.
Which is not ideal.

Comment: Why don't you write the code you want to test in a way that it does not matter what the environment is? e.g. ``String commonPath(String pathA, String pathB, String pathSep)`` and then test that passing in windows paths and the windows separator and also with linux paths and the linux separator.

Comment: In general this would work if the method would use Strings. But in this case the method relies heavily on Path and it's methods. Which use different implementations depending on the OS.

Comment: The intention of Path objects and the like being platform specific is to isolate application code from the platform-specific stuff. So in theory you should be able to work with a Path in the same way irrespective of the platform you are on. If you are putting platform specific code into your application (or tests) then perhaps that is not the right approach. If you have no application specific code then you are trusting the Path class (and related stuff) to do things correctly (and to have been tested as such) so you do not need to have multi-platform tests in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write most of your test cases so that they work on both platforms. Windows `Path` handling is very tolerant to using Linux paths. If you carefully frame your test data so that you never convert a Path back to String your Linux Path tests should work on Windows because you can omit mentioning a Windows drive letter as a String value.

For example try these tests on both platforms. Windows Path handling automatically deals with the wrong style of path separators internally but this is never exposed unless you convert `Path` back to `String`:

```
@Test void testsCommonToAllPlatforms() {
  Assertions.assertEquals(Path.of("/a/b"), commonPath(Path.of("/a/b/c"), Path.of("/a/b/d")));
  Assertions.assertEquals(Path.of("a/b"),  commonPath(Path.of("a/b/c"),  Path.of("a/b/d")));
  Assertions.assertEquals(Path.of("/"),    commonPath(Path.of("/a/b/c"), Path.of("/d/e/f")));
  Assertions.assertEquals(        null,    commonPath(Path.of("a/b/c"),  Path.of("d/e/f")));
}
```

This will leave you to setup a few extra Windows specific tests (in additional to above) which could include drive letters, and you'll need access to a Windows build machine now and then to verify no regressions:

```
@EnabledOnOs(OS.WINDOWS)
@Test void testJustForWindows() {
  Assertions.assertEquals(Path.of("C:/Winnt"), commonPath(Path.of("C:/Winnt/System32"), Path.of("C:/Winnt/System64"))));
  Assertions.assertEquals(               null, commonPath(Path.of("C:/Winnt/System32"), Path.of("F:/Winnt/System32")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it is possible as the JDK for Windows only contains the `WindowsPath` class.
The bare minimum for this to work is, that the classes `WindowsPath` and `UnixPath` are present.