# Java: How to add two integer streams and produce a new stream

Tags: java, java-stream

so I have

```
Stream<Integer> stream1 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Stream<Integer> stream2 = Stream.of(6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

I want to make `stream3` which is the sum of the elements of `stream1` and `stream2`, in other words, `7, 9, 11, 13, 15`.

How would I go about doing this with stream operations?

Comment: Show us your attempts and tell us what's not working.

Comment: What if the two streams not have the same size?

Comment: we assume two streams always have the same size

Answer (score 2):

Since streams aren’t well suited for this I suggest you collect the elements first, then do the pairwise adding in a new stream:

```
    IntStream stream1 = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    IntStream stream2 = IntStream.of(6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    int[] arr1 = stream1.toArray();
    int[] arr2 = stream2.toArray();

    IntStream sumStream = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
            .map(index -> arr1[index] + arr2[index]);

    sumStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> 7
> 9
> 11
> 13
> 15
> ```

You want to check your assumption that there are the same number of elements in both streams, of course, and react adequately if not, may throw an exception. I’ll leave that to you.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`zip`](https://rxmarbles.com/#zip) operation.

Here is how you can accomplish your task using  [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Streams#zip`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Stream<Integer> stream1 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Stream<Integer> stream2 = Stream.of(6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

Streams.zip(stream1, stream2, Integer::sum)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output:

```
7
9
11
13
15
```

See also:

- [Zipping collections in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip)
- [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Answer (score 1):

There is the same `zip` method as @caco3 mentioned, but from [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library, that expand standart stream api:

```
List<Integer> zip = StreamEx
    .zip(stream1.collect(toList()), stream2.collect(toList()), Integer::sum)
    .collect(toList());

System.out.println(zip);
```

[StreamEx.zip](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#zip-java.util.List-java.util.List-java.util.function.BiFunction-)