# How to merge two list of POJOS using stream JAVA 8 modifying some values when necessary

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Hope you can help me. I'll try to make myself clear about the title of the question.
I have one POJO like this

```
public class Factor {
    private int id;
    private String item;
    private int unitId;
    private Double factor;

    // constructor getters and setters
}
```

I have two `List` of this class with data from two different tables in two different DB.

The `equals`method is defined this way

```
import com.google.common.base.Objects;
//....
@Override
public boolean equals( Object o ) {
    if ( this == o )
        return true;
    if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() )
        return false;
    Factor that = (Factor) o;
    return getUnitId() == that.getUnitId() &&
               Objects.equal(getItem(), that.getItem());
}
```

so two objects are considered equals when they have the same `item` and `unitId` attributes.

Let's say I have these two list:

```
List<Factor> listA = new ArrayList<>();
listA.add(new Factor(1, "Item1", 1, 0.5));
listA.add(new Factor(2, "Item1", 2, 0.6));
listA.add(new Factor(3, "Item2", 1, 1.0));
listA.add(new Factor(4, "Item3", 1, 2.0));

List<Factor> listB = new ArrayList<>();
listB.add(new Factor(0, "Item1", 1, 0.8));
listB.add(new Factor(0, "Item1", 2, 0.9));
listB.add(new Factor(0, "Item4", 1, 1.0));
listB.add(new Factor(0, "Item5", 1, 2.0));
```

Taking the `equals`method into account, the first two elements of the lists should be considered equals.

The reason why the `ids` in the B list are all `0`, is because that table has not an `id` field.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a new list by merging these two lists, but if the objects are equals, it should take the `id` from  `listA` and the factor from `listB`.

In this way, the result list would have the following objects

```
(1, "Item1", 1, 0.8)
(2, "Item1", 2, 0.9)
(0, "Item4", 1, 1.0)
(0, "Item5", 1, 2.0)
```

I know how to compare both list with `stream` and filter which objects are equals or different but does anybody know how to get a new object combining the equals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you also have overridden `hashCode` method you can use `toMap` collector:

```
Collection<Factor> values = Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                                      Function.identity(), (a, b) -> {
        return new Factor(a.getId(), a.getItem(), a.getUnitId(), b.getFactor());
    })).values();
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a "zip" function. However, there isn't one in the Stream API (at least in Java 8, I don't know about newer versions).

You can find how to write a `zip` method yourself in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip).

Using the answer by siki, we get this method:

```
public static<A, B, C> Stream<C> zip(Stream<? extends A> a,
                                     Stream<? extends B> b,
                                     BiFunction<? super A, ? super B, ? extends C> zipper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(zipper);
    Spliterator<? extends A> aSpliterator = Objects.requireNonNull(a).spliterator();
    Spliterator<? extends B> bSpliterator = Objects.requireNonNull(b).spliterator();

    // Zipping looses DISTINCT and SORTED characteristics
    int characteristics = aSpliterator.characteristics() & bSpliterator.characteristics() &
            ~(Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.SORTED);

    long zipSize = ((characteristics & Spliterator.SIZED) != 0)
            ? Math.min(aSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(), bSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown())
            : -1;

    Iterator<A> aIterator = Spliterators.iterator(aSpliterator);
    Iterator<B> bIterator = Spliterators.iterator(bSpliterator);
    Iterator<C> cIterator = new Iterator<C>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return aIterator.hasNext() && bIterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public C next() {
            return zipper.apply(aIterator.next(), bIterator.next());
        }
    };

    Spliterator<C> split = Spliterators.spliterator(cIterator, zipSize, characteristics);
    return (a.isParallel() || b.isParallel())
            ? StreamSupport.stream(split, true)
            : StreamSupport.stream(split, false);
}
```

We can use it like this:

```
List<Factor> result = zip(list1.stream(), list2.stream(),
        (x, y) -> x.equals(y) ? new Factor(x.getId(), y.getItem(), y.getUnitId(), y.getFactor()) : y) // you might want to create a copy of y instead
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The third argument is basically saying how we want to merge the items. Here the lambda says:

> If the items of the two objects are equal, then we create a new item with the ID from the first item (from list1) and everything else from the second item (from list2). Otherwise, just use the second item.

This will result in some of the objects in `result` to be brand new ones, and some be existing ones. If you want them to all be brand new ones, replace `y` at the very end of that line with:

```
new Factor(y.getID(), y.getItem(), y.getUnitId(), y.getFactor())
```

Comment: Just a question, must the lists have the same size?

Comment: @pburgov the list don’t have to be the same size. The result list will be as long as the shorter list of the two.

Comment: You are right, the order of items matters. Otherwise how are you going to decide which item corresponds to which? Should the item with ID 1 have the factor 0.9 or 0.8? @Adrian

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper for your answer.