# Run two streams and make an object from these

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two Lists

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList( "1" , "2" , "3" );
List<String> b = Arrays.asList( "a" , "b" , "c" );
```

and a class

```
class Obj{
   String a;
   String b;
   public Obj(String a, String b){
       this.a=a;
       this.b=b;
   }
}
```

I have to convert every element 2 lists into an object of above class.
Resulting into a list of object of Obj in something like this -

```
[ Obj("1","a") , Obj("2","a") , Obj("3","a") ]
```

I know i can do it simply by running a loop.

```
List<Obj> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for( int i=0; i<allAttributes.size(); i++){
    arrayList.add( new Obj(a[i],b[i]) );
}
```

Wanted to know if it can be done in Java 8 some elegant way.

Comment: What is wrong with using that loop?

Comment: no problem just curious if can be done in better way in java8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that a and b lists are of same size, this should do the trick,

```
List<Obj> objList = IntStream.range(0, a.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new Obj(a.get(i), b.get(i)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This will be break if `b.size< a.size`

Comment: I assume  both the arrays are of same size.

Comment: both arrays are of same size for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: Can we also some how add object only if b.get(i) is not empty string?

Comment: @nekkel add a `filter(i -> !b.get(i).isEmpty())` before mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to implement a Zip-Operation for lists and streams (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip/32342172) for example), but you could use the existing method `com.google.common.collect.Streams.zip` in Guava Streams. That way, your code could look like this:

```
final List<String> a = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
final List<String> b = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<Obj> objs = Streams.zip(a.stream(), b.stream(), (pa, pb) -> new Obj(pa, pb))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can further filter the stream afterwards, e.g.:

```
List<Obj> objs = Streams.zip(a.stream(), b.stream(), (pa, pb) -> new Obj(pa, pb))
            .filter(obj -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(obj.b))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```