# How to reduce a Java stream to a boolean value based upon comparing consecutive list elements

Tags: java, functional-programming, reduce, collectors

As a refactoring exercise, I'm trying to take something like this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < orderedList.size(); i++) {
        Object object1 = ordered.get(i - 1);
        Object object2 = ordered.get(i);
        if (isDifferent(object1, object2)) return true;
    }

    return false;
```

into a simple Java functional statement. At first glance, I'm processing elements of a list sequentially, so `reduce()` sounded promising, but

1. It would require carrying along a boolean value, which loses me the previous element; or
2. carrying along the previous element of the list, which means I need to put it in some kind of wrapper object, or kludgy use of `Optional` or another `List` as a wrapper, in order to keep track of whether I have a difference or not.

So, I see ways I can use a reduce operation, but it would be more complicated and hard to understand than the for-loop original.

I looked at creating a custom collector, but ran into the same issues.

Is this a proper use of reduce, or am I just tempted because I know I can use it to process sequential values against a previous iteration? If it's a proper use, how can I compose the functions to reduce myself to a boolean?

Thanks for help with this thought exercise.

Comment: Streams suit processing each element in isolation, or adjacent elements when reducing. You can “abuse” the pattern by reading/writing to variables outside the stream, but at that point you’re better off with an old school loop.

Comment: What's wrong about just leaving it? The stream will deprive you of the possibility to short-circuit. So performance-wise you'll be worse off with streams, unless `isDifferent` evaluates to `true` exceedingly rarely. In terms of readability you've already seen yourself that it doesn't play out nicely.

Comment: @Bohemian Reduction is not defined as an operation processing adjacent elements; it requires an associative function, so it may process, e.g. `(a×b)×(c×d)`, which does not fit the OP’s task. You’d have to map all elements to a type holding an interval (first and last element) and the boolean state. Besides the complexity of that, you’d lose the short-circuiting…

Answer (score 2):

Because you're indexing two `List`s with a for-loop, you can replace it with an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and reduce it with [`IntStream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate)):

```
return IntStream.range(1, orderedList.size())
                .anyMatch(i -> isDifferent(ordered.get(i - 1), ordered.get(i)));
```

Although, I don't really see this providing much benefit, so it may be more readable to just keep it as a for-loop.

Comment: Actually, I kind of like that. I was trying to get rid of the "i-1" with the reduce operation, and when i shoved i+1/i-1 in a `forEach` it looked worse than the original, but this is more readable even with the manual indexing.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental operation here is called "zipping": given two streams of `A`s and `B`s and a combining operator `(A, B) -> C`, you can create a stream of `C`s (truncating to the shorter input stream). Assuming you have such a function

```
<A, B, C> Stream<C> zip
 (Stream<? extends A> as, Stream<? extends B> bs,
  BiFunction<? super A, ? super B, ? extends C> combine);
```

You can implement your operation as

```
zip(ordered.stream(), ordered.stream().skip(1), this::isDifferent).anyMatch(x -> x);
// ordered: a b c d ... y z
// skipped: b c d ... y z
// zipped : (a, b) (b, c) (c, d) ... (y, z)
```

There is no `zip` in the standard library. If you're using something like Guava, you may check whether it has this operation, e.g. [here's one](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/28.0-jre). Or, you can implement it yourself and stick it in some utility class, at which point you may want to [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529010/5684257). I will reproduce the code listed there (which appears to be cribbed from a beta version of the actual Streams API):

> ```
> public static<A, B, C> Stream<C> zip(Stream<? extends A> a,
>                                      Stream<? extends B> b,
>                                      BiFunction<? super A, ? super B, ? extends C> zipper) {
>     Objects.requireNonNull(zipper);
>     Spliterator<? extends A> aSpliterator = Objects.requireNonNull(a).spliterator();
>     Spliterator<? extends B> bSpliterator = Objects.requireNonNull(b).spliterator();
>
>     // Zipping looses DISTINCT and SORTED characteristics
>     int characteristics = aSpliterator.characteristics() & bSpliterator.characteristics() &
>             ~(Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.SORTED);
>
>     long zipSize = ((characteristics & Spliterator.SIZED) != 0)
>             ? Math.min(aSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(), bSpliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown())
>             : -1;
>
>     Iterator<A> aIterator = Spliterators.iterator(aSpliterator);
>     Iterator<B> bIterator = Spliterators.iterator(bSpliterator);
>     Iterator<C> cIterator = new Iterator<C>() {
>         @Override
>         public boolean hasNext() {
>             return aIterator.hasNext() && bIterator.hasNext();
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public C next() {
>             return zipper.apply(aIterator.next(), bIterator.next());
>         }
>     };
>
>     Spliterator<C> split = Spliterators.spliterator(cIterator, zipSize, characteristics);
>     return (a.isParallel() || b.isParallel())
>            ? StreamSupport.stream(split, true)
>            : StreamSupport.stream(split, false);
> }
> ```

Comment: Hadn't thought of zipping the same list into itself, and didn't realize any (relatively) standard libraries supported zip. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it is as simple as this from your logic?

```
return orderedList.stream.distinct().count() != 1; // assuming that you have equals and 
                                                  //  hashcode method overridden for 
                                                  // your object.
```