# Is there a possibility to make a new Stream out of 2 Streams in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am quite new to Java 8 Streams and have a question with faced me, doing homework for University.
If I have 2 Intstreams with have the same amount of Integers as

```java
IntStream one = Arrays.stream(test.matrix).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream);
IntStream two = Arrays.stream(test2.matrix).flatMapToInt(Arrays :: stream);
IntStream difference = one - two ???
```

is it possible to generate a new Stream holding the elementwhise difference of the two streams?
I have tried a lot like using `stream.iterator();` which worked, but I am not allowed to use "normal" iterators, and should solve it with lambda expressions.
Has anyone a tip on how to solve this?

Comment: Is this helpful? [Zipping Collections in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip) Or this? [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation combining two streams/lists is often called `zip`.
Unfortunately this operation is not provided in the Java 8 standard library.
You can read more about how users defined their own zip functions here: [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Answer (score 2):

Overall, you'll essentially just be iterating the arrays by index. If you only iterate by elements then you cannot combine the streams in a way analogous to a zip operation. First, define what subtracting matrices looks like. For now, I'll only define same size matrices:

```
public static void subtract(int[] origin, int[] operand) {
    if (origin.length != operand.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array lengths must match");
    //Make a new result, so as not to muck with the original array
    return IntStream.range(0, origin.length).map(i -> origin[i] - operand[i]).toArray();
}
```

Then generating the difference is a matter of passing in those matrices directly, and the stream is used simply as a matter of iterating both sets of elements. Thus the task could also be accomplished with a simple vanilla for loop. Nonetheless:

```
int[] result = subtract(one, two);
```

We can abstract the logic above as well to allow a more flexible set of operations:

```
public static int[] operate(int[] origin, int[] operand, IntBiFunction operation) {
    if (origin.length != operand.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array lengths must match");
    return IntStream.range(0, origin.length)
            .forEach(i -> result[i] = operation.apply(origin[i], operand[i]))
            .toArray();
}

public static void subtract(int[] origin, int[] operand) {
    //Producing result from each index matched element
    return operate(origin, operand, (one, two) -> one - two);
}
```

This is where I'd see more of an advantage of using anything function api related.

If you wish to utilize a return of `IntStream` instead of `int[]`, you *can*, but you'll run into the original issue of having to reference the arrays by index. You could really push it and supply an arbitrary amount of operations (`IntBiFunction... operations`), but I think you risk overcomplicating your logic.