# Two primitive type streams to one stream of pairs

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two collections:

```
List<String> names = ...
List<Long> counts = ...
```

I know that these two collections are equal and each value at position n in one list matches to the other list.

I want to perform a transformation where as an output I receive:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
```

where `Foo` is a record defined as:

```
record Foo(String name, long count)
```

For now this is my solution:

```
List<Foo> foos = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
                          .mapToObj(i -> new Foo(names.get(i), counts.get(i)))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**My question**: Is there an other way to pair and collect Foo objects?

Comment: Please post your question on code review.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala - That is really bad advice.  Code review is not questions about how to do something differently.

Comment: Of course, there are other ways, e.g. you could use a loop. Regarding the Stream API, this is the simplest solution. Since it works and you don’t have any actual problems with it, don‘t bother thinking about alternatives.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: you are going right ! ..you can further use libraries that can all fancy your code. Useful Link https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip

Comment: The linked original question shows another way. However like @Holger I’d stay with the code you have if that were me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution relies on the same size of both collections, so we should focus on this. Let's put the Java Stream API aside for a while since there is no other way traversing two collections simultaneously than using `IntStream` range with indices. Simply put, Java Stream API is not suitable for this use-case.

You need to ensure that no `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown upon calling [`List::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-). I prefer two ways:

1. Two iterators with conjugated conditions:

   ```
   List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
   while (namesIterator.hasNext() && countsIterator.hasNext()) {
       Foo foo = new Foo(namesIterator.next(), countsIterator.next());
       fooList.add(foo);
   }
   ```
2. Using for-each iteration with indices up to the lower bound of both list sizes:

   ```
   int bound = Math.min(names.size(), counts.size());
   List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i=0; i<bound; i++) {
       Foo foo = new Foo(names.get(i), counts.get(i);
       fooList.add(foo);
   }
   ```

   .. which is similar to the Java Stream API way:

   ```
   List<Foo> fooList = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, Math.min(names.size(), counts.size()))
                                .mapToObj(i -> new Foo(names.get(i), counts.get(i)))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

There are also external libraries with dedicated methods to zipping such as [`Streams::zip`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) from Guava or [`Seq::zip`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) from jOOλ. The zipping mechanism is pretty much the same across libraries.

The current design of Java Stream API is not suitable for it.