# Using Java Stream - process two halves of stream independently

Tags: java, java-stream

I have currently this code:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
return IntStream.range(0, costs.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> new int[]{costs[i][0]-costs[i][1], i})
  .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(d -> d[0]))
  .mapToInt(s -> 
    counter.getAndIncrement() < costs.length/2 ? costs[s[1]][0] : costs[s[1]][1]
  )
  .sum();
```

Where I compute diff of two elements of an array and then sort it and in the end I need to process two halves independently.

Is there any better way to do this than using `AtomicInteger` as a counter? Is there some method like `mapToIntWithIndex` that is accessible inside JDK (not in external libraries)? Is there something like `zip()` in python where I could join indices together with stream? If not is there any plan to add this to next Java releases?

Comment: If you just want a `zip`, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip).

Comment: This is not a reliable way to do this. You are relying on elements of the stream being processed in order, and that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @AndyTurner I thought it is, unless I start using parallel processing?

Comment: No, there is no such guaranty, whether you use sequential or parallel. It’s just an implementation detail when the processing happens in a particular order. A different implementation could determine that `sum()` is a terminal operation that does not depend on the order, hence, the `sorted` step is obsolete and can be elided.

Comment: @Holger - so you say that we should never use `sorted()` in Java streams (to mitigate potential future implementation differences)?

Comment: No, I’m saying that you should only use `sorted` in a Java stream when the subsequent operations are specified to respect the resulting order (which implies being dependent on the order at all). There is nothing wrong with, e.g. `sorted().toArray()` or `sorted().collect(toList())` or `sorted().collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))`. Likewise, inserting `map` operations between `sorted` and the terminal operation isn’t wrong, as long as the mapping function does not assume to be evaluated in that order. `sum()` obviously is not an operation depending on the order.

Comment: @Holger it's just `int[][] costs`

Comment: `int[][] sorted = Arrays.stream(costs).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0] - a[1])).toArray(int[][]::new); return IntStream.range(0, sorted.length) .map(ix -> sorted[ix][ix < sorted.length/2? 0: 1]) .sum();`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a reliable way to do this. The Streams API [makes it clear](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) that functions used in maps should not be stateful.

> Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the behavioral parameters to the stream operations are stateful.

If you use stateful functions, it may *appear* to work, but because you aren't using it according to the documentation, the behaviour is technically undefined, and could break in future versions of Java.

Collect to a list, and then process the two halves of the list:

```
List<int[]> list = /* your stream up to and including the sort */.collect(toList());
int sum = list.subList(0,    half       ).stream().mapToInt(s -> costs[s[1]][0]).sum()
        + list.subList(half, list.size()).stream().mapToInt(s -> costs[s[1]][1]).sum();
```

Actually, I'd be tempted to write it as for loops, as I just find it easier on the eye:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int[][] s : list.subList(0, half))           sum += costs[s[1]][0];
for (int[][] s : list.subList(half, list.size())) sum += costs[s[1]][1];
```

Comment: you could also do list.stream().limit(half).... and list.stream.skip(half)....