# Java 8 Stream vs For loop - modify objects in a list, using properties of objects in another list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following lists:

```
List<Token> originals
List<Token> modified
```

The Token class is as follows:

```
class Token
{
    private String value;
    private String rawValue;
}
```

I want to replace the `rawValue` of all the `Token` objects in `originals`, with the `rawValue` of the `Token` object at the corresponding index in `modified`. Both the lists are guaranteed to be equal in length.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
for i in originals.length
    originals[i].rawValue = modified[i].rawValue
```

Is there a way to do this using Stream? Or is using a For loop simpler and more readable here?

Comment: I would definitely use a for loop or while loop for this. If you want to use streams, you'd probably want to [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17640754/276052) the streams, and work with pairs of Token objects.

Comment: You can use an IntStream to iterate but honestly the Stream API is not designed to mutate the original Collection therefore I would recommend using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.range(0, originals.size())
        .forEach(i ->  originals.get(i).rawValue = modified.get(i).rawValue);
```