# Java generics problem - required T, provided capture or vice-versa

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractPoint<PointType extends AbstractPoint<PointType>> {
    public abstract double getX();
    public abstract double getY();
    public abstract double rho();

    // Find the distance between two points
    public final <T extends AbstractPoint<T>> double distance(T other) {
        return vectorTo(other).rho();
    }

    // Find vector from one point to another.
    public abstract <T extends AbstractPoint<T>> PointType vectorTo(T other);

    // other methods ...
}
```

Classes `OrthogonalPoint` and `PolarPoint` extend the abstract class:

```
public class OrthogonalPoint extends AbstractPoint<OrthogonalPoint> {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public OrthogonalPoint(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() { return this.x; }

    public double getY() { return this.y; }

    public double rho() { return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)); }

    public double theta() { return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x); }

    public <T extends AbstractPoint<T>> OrthogonalPoint vectorTo(T other) {
        return new OrthogonalPoint(other.getX() - this.x, other.getY() - this.y);
    }
}
```

```
public class PolarPoint extends AbstractPoint<PolarPoint> {
    private double rho;
    private double theta;

    public PolarPoint(double x, double y) {
        this.rho = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
        this.theta = Math.atan2(y, x);
    }

    public double getX() { return this.rho() * Math.cos(this.theta()); }

    public double getY() { return this.rho() * Math.sin(this.theta()); }

    public double rho() { return this.rho; }

    public double theta() { return this.theta; }

    public <T extends AbstractPoint<T>> PolarPoint vectorTo(T other) {
        return new PolarPoint(other.getX() - this.getX(), other.getY() - this.getY());
    }
}
```

With this code, I can correctly calculate the distance between points no matter whether they are of same type (orthogonal or polar).
Now I add another class called `Route`:

```
public class Route {

    private final List<? extends AbstractPoint<?>> points = new ArrayList<>();

    // 'point' in 'this.points.add(point)' underlined red
    public <T extends AbstractPoint<T>> void appendPoint(T point) { this.points.add(point); }

    public <T extends AbstractPoint<T>> void removePoint(T point) { this.points.remove(point);  }

    // 'point' in '.distance(point)' underlined red
    public double routeDistance() {
        return this.points.stream().skip(1).mapToDouble(point ->
                this.points.get(this.points.indexOf(point) - 1).distance(point)).sum();
    }
}
```

A route is an ordered number of points whose length is defined as the sum of the distances of the points in the sequence. So, if a route consists of three points (p1, p2, and p3) the distance of the route is `p1.distance(p2) + p2.distance(p3)`.
However, some places (look at the comments in `Route`) in my code are underlined red:

```
// in appendPoint function
Required type: capture of ? extends AbstractPoint<?>
     Provided: T

// in routeDistance function
Required type: T
     Provided: capture of ? extends AbstractPoint<?>
```

I want to be able to add any type of point to the points list and the call `routeDistance` function to calculate the length of the route. What is wrong with my solution - how should I change my generics (in any class)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: @luk2302 I do not think so. If the collection came in as a parameter to a function, then yes, but my collection is a class variable. As I understand from your link, my collection is both a producer and a consumer. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: No, the way you got the data does not matter, variable, field, parameter, … - it has extends as part of the generic and therefore is a producer, can only be a producer, you cannot add stuff to it.

Comment: If you want it to be both a consumer and a producer the generic type parameter of the collection must not use extends or super.

Comment: So how can I create a Route, that has a class variable points that is a collection, and I can add both Orthogonal and Polar points to this collection and also iterate over it and do things with the items? If the collection would be just List<T>, I would have to make Route generic and I can't add different types of points to the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that you are both adding data to the `points` list, and taking data out of the list, so you should not use `extends` or `super`. (See also: [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super))

```
private final List<AbstractPoint<?>> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

Next, you will see that there is an error at the `.distance(point)` call. This is because there is no type that can be used as the type parameter `T` of the `distance` method, that also satisfies the constraint `T extends AbstractPoint<T>`. Note that the type of `point` is `AbstractPoint<?>`, and `AbstractPoint<?>` can't be `T`, because `AbstractPoint<?>` does not extend `AbstractPoint<AbstractPoint<?>>`. See the problem?

From what I can see, the way you have written `distance` does not allow you to find the distance between two `AbstractPoint`s. One of the points must be a concrete type.

In fact, `distance` and `vectorTo` doesn't actually need the generic parameter. It can just take a `AbstractPoint<?>`:

```
public final double distance(AbstractPoint<?> other) {
    return vectorTo(other).rho();
}

public abstract PointType vectorTo(AbstractPoint<?> other);
```

This now allows you to pass in `AbstractPoint<?>` to `distance`.

Side note: your current implementation of `routeDistance` using `indexOf` is not very efficient, as it goes over the list once for every point in  the list. You can do this with a [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529010/5133585) operation instead. Using the `zip` method in the linked answer:

```
return zip(points.stream(), points.stream().skip(1), AbstractPoint::distance)
    .mapToDouble(x -> x).sum();
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot from this. This was exactly what I wanted to achieve. However, I will keep my current implementation of routeDistance as performance is not that important for this project and I do not wish to add such a big and complicated method to my code.