# Combine two streams and call method

Tags: java, asynchronous, stream, flatmap

I have a problem how to stream asynchornously and call a method,
e.g.

```
List<User> users = List.of(user1, user2, user3);
List<Workplace> worklpaces = List.of(workplace1,workplace2,workplace3)
```

It's always the same `users.size == workplaces.size`

we have a function mapping

```
public List<UserWithWorkplace> combineUserWithWorkplaceAndType(List<User> users,List<Workplace> 
worklpaces, Type someRandomtype) {

//here is the problem it wont it should be get
//List<UserWithWorkplace>.size == users.size == workplaces.size


return users.stream().flatMap(user -> 
                              worklpaces.stream()
                              .map(worklpace -> mapping(user,worklpace, someRandomtype)))
                              .toList()
}


private UserWithWorkplace mapping( User user, Workplace workplace,Type someRandomtype){

//cominging and returning user with workplace
}
```

How to achieve that result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to create pairs of `(user, workplace)` from two separate `users` an `workplaces` streams, this operation is normally called "zipping".

Guava library provide [`Streams.zip(Stream, Steam, Function)`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method for this. In your case the code would look like:

```
Stream<UserWithWorkplace> zipped = Streams.zip(
    users.stream(), 
    worklpaces.stream(), 
    (u, w) -> this.mapping(u, w, someRandomtype));
```

However your example code uses `List` and not `Stream` to represent data. I'm not sure if you have to use Java streams for this, a simple `for` loop with `i` index might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a zipping operation.

If using Google Guava, you can do this to combine them:

```
Streams.zip(users.stream(), workplaces.stream(), (user, workplace) -> mapping(user, workplace, someType))
```

You can also find some other implementations of this operation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)