# java: implementing vector addition with streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there an elegant way to interoperate two streams?

```
/**
 *  e.g. add([1, -1, 5], [2, 3, 4]) -> [3, 2, 9]
 */
Stream<Integer> add(Stream<Integer> a, Stream<Integer> b)  {
    //?
}
```

I would hate to collect both streams to do the thing in a for-loop, just to stream the result again

Comment: I think the operation you're looking for is called [zipping](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

Comment: What you are looking for is the zip operation, for which there is unfortunately no method in the standard library. See: [Bridge the Gap of Zip Operation](https://dzone.com/articles/bridge-the-gap-of-zip-operation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think you've provided the best answer and crossed it out for no reason.

Comment: The problem started before this method, at the place where you decided that a `Stream` was a good way to represent a vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stream<Integer> add(Stream<Integer> a, Stream<Integer> b)  {
   Iterator<Integer> i=a.iterator();
   return b.map(bz-> i.hasNext() ?  bz + i.next() : bz);
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? Is there any guarantee that 'i.hasNext()' is run sequentially with map? eg could elements 1-5 be filtered before a map call is appied?

Comment: tried with         add(Stream.of(1, 2, 3), Stream.of(4, 5, 6)).forEach(System.out::println).
Works well

Comment: I would say the filter doesn't add anything. Your example doesn't really test it since your lists have the same number of elements. If a has more elements than b then it would matter if it is called 'filter, map; filter, map' vs 'filter; filter, map, map'

Comment: I just wrote a couple of randomly generated tests with larger a or larger b - works fine. @matt does have a point that it looks a little bit fishy though

Comment: you are right, edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this question really highlights why you probably shouldn't be doing what you're doing.

1st. You're adding three pairs of int's, and your using a Stream so you have to use Integer. That's huge overhead relative to the operation.

2nd. The concept of Stream is not limited to ordered sets of data.

For that reason collecting to a list makes sense because you're explicitly operating on a finite ordered dataset.

```
List<Integer> la = a.collect( Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> lb = b.collect( Collectors.toList());

Stream<Integer> result = IntStream.range( 0, la.size() ).mapToObj( 
    i -> la.get(i) && lb.get(j) 
);
```

It might be more stream-like to use a.iterator() instead of lists because you wouldn't be limited to finite datasets.

```
Iterator<Integer> ia = a.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> ib = b.iterator();

if( ! ia.hasNext() || ! ib.hasNext() ) return Stream.empty();

return Stream.iterate( 
    ia.next() + ib.next(), 
    last -> ia.hasNext() && ib.hasNext(), 
    last -> ia.next() + ib.next() );
```

Comment: You can not combine two `boolean` values with `+`. So `ia.hasNext() + ib.hasNext()` most probably should be `ia.hasNext() && ib.hasNext()`. Your two points at the beginning of the answer are correct, but the conclusion should not be to collect into lists, but not to use Streams in the first place.