# How to use stream instead of for loop travel three different type list in same time in java

Tags: java, java-stream

#### description:

- three lists size are always equal.

#### example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Foo> list3 = Arrays.asList(new Foo(),new Foo(),new Foo());
    for (int i=0;i<list1.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(output(list1.get(i),list2.get(i),list3.get(i)));
    }
}

private static String output(String first, Integer second, Foo third) {
    return first + second + third;
}

public class Foo {
    public int get(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

- result:

```
aaa1org.example.Foo@4aa298b7
bbb2org.example.Foo@7d4991ad
ccc3org.example.Foo@28d93b30
```

#### what I have tried:

##### first try:

```
Stream test = IntStream.range(0,list1.size())
    .Stream.concat(Stream.of(list1),Stream.of(list2),Stream.of(list3)).map(this::output).map(xxx::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

- Apparently it didn't work.Sry I'm new in using stream.

1. I don't know what should I input in `xxx` part and got stuck in here.
2. I also don‘t know how to use `map` in nested method call.
3. I also don't know how to collect three different types list.

- maybe I should use map to organize them?

##### use a class to organize them:

```
public class Bar {
    String list1;
    Integer list2;
    Foo list3;

    Bar(String list1Con,Integer list2Con,Foo list3Con){
        list1 = list1Con;
        list2 = list2Con;
        list3 = list3Con;
    }

    public Map<String,Object> get(int index) {
        return new HashMap<String,Object>() {{
            put("list1",list1);
            put("list2",list2);
            put("list3",list3);
        }};
    }
}

List<Bar> listBar = Arrays.asList(
    new Bar("aaa",1,new Foo()),
    new Bar("bbb",2,new Foo()),
    new Bar("ccc",3,new Foo())
);
IntStream.range(0, listBar.size()).mapToObj(listBar::get).map(Bar::get).map(Map::values).forEach(System.out::println);
```

- Apparently it didn't work, either.

1. I don't know how to use parameter after `mapToObj` to apply in `Bar::get`

#### question:

- How to use stream instead of for loop travel three different type list in same time in java.

Comment: As far as I know Java Streams don't support this natively. There are several possible solutions, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip and https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip

Comment: To write a useful review on your "use a class to organize them" approach, I'd need to know more about the underlying problem. Currently, it's hard to understand why the `Foo` class has a `get(int)` method, and still needs three distinct instances.

Comment: @Ralf Kleberhoff just want the `Foo` do something avoid printing it like `Foo@4aa298b7`. I think this one make it unnecessary difficult. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frame challenge:

- Is it a good idea to use streams for that situation, especially for a streams beginner?
- Are there better architectures that avoid the three-parallel-lists problem?

### Using streams

Your problem is not what streams are meant for.

The typical streams usage is: have some collection (or similar source), independently operate on every element of that collection, and return some result.

You don't have a single collection source, and you don't need a result, you just have a side effect (printing). And the power of streams (e.g. parallel execution) would probably break your expectation, that the side effects happen in order

> Sry I'm new in using stream.

You can make it work if you find or write an adapter that creates a stream of triples (String/Integer/Foo) from your three lists, and then use stream functions to operate on that stream, but I'd recommend to not follow that path until you got some more experience with streams.

In general, I don't see benefit in transforming each and every loop into streams expressions. There are many situations where streams make your code more concise and better readable, but in your case, IMHO the loop is perfectly fine.

### Architecture

You have three lists of equal size, and the elements at identical indices belong together. Most of the time, this is a hint that the combination of these three things (String, Integer and Foo) has a domain meaning, and is worth a class of its own (let's call it `MyCombination`, as of course I don't know what would be a proper name in your domain).

Then your three-lists problem vanishes, you only have a single `List<MyCombination>` where you can easily apply streams functions.

Comment: +1 for your effort now. I got same idea (`use List<MyCombination>`) in past 30mins, I have already update what I have tried. pls check it. sry I'm new in using stream so I can't easily apply streams functions.

Comment: Btw, I do need the result in next step, just use print as a simple usage of result in example.

Comment: Oh I got the most important idea in your answer. The stream is not always better than for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really insist* of using a `Stream` instead of a `for` loop, you can try this:

```java
public final class Foo 
{
  public final int get( final int i ) { return i; }
}

…

private static String output( final String first, final Integer second, final Foo third, final int index ) 
{
  return first + second + third.get( index );
}

…

final List<String> list1 = List.of( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" );
final List<Integer> list2 = List.of( 1, 2, 3 );
final List<Foo> list3 = List.of( new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo() );

IntStream.range( 0, list1.size() )
  .mapToObj( i -> output( list1.get( i ), list2.get( i ), list3.get( i ), i ) )
  .forEach( System.out::println );
```

If someone says that this is more or less what is used in real functional languages as the replacement for a `for` loop, they might be right …

Python programmers will have seen something similar:

```py
for i in range( 0, 6 ):
  output = list1 [i] + list2 [i] + list3 [i].get( i )
```

Comment: I fix some typo in your answer. +1 for great answer.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori – Thanks!!

Comment: Sry I can't accept your answer, although you did solve the problem in my post, but Ralf Kleberhoff found the real issue behide my post and solve my real problem in real work. Sry again, already +1 for your effort.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori  – No issue, everything's ok. I took your specification/task description as something you were asking for to solve an exercise in school, not as a real world problem. Because for a real world issue, Ralf is fully correct: streams are not *always* the best solution, not even *always* a proper solution. But on the other hand, it widens your mind when you try it anyways.